# How can I run an external program from C and parse its output?

Tags: c, external-process

I've got a utility that outputs a list of files required by a game.  How can I run that utility within a C program and grab its output so I can act on it within the same program?

UPDATE: Good call on the lack of information.  The utility spits out a series of strings, and this is supposed to be portable across Mac/Windows/Linux.  Please note, I'm looking for a programmatic way to execute the utility and retain its output (which goes to stdout).

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125828/capturing-stdout-from-a-system-command-optimally

Comment: If you want stderr as well you can redirect, for example call ls nonexistant-name 2>&1

Comment: This is not a duplicate; the linked question is **C++ specific**, while this question is about **C**.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question as it not a duplicate, it's about C not C++

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405985/linux-3-0-executing-child-process-with-piped-stdin-stdout

Comment: See also: [C: Run a System Command and Get Output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646241/c-run-a-system-command-and-get-output)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

For simple problems in Unix-ish environments try [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/popen.html).

From the man page:

> The popen() function opens a process by creating a pipe, forking and invoking the shell.

If you use the read mode this is exactly what you asked for. I don't know if it is implemented in Windows.

For more complicated problems you want to look up inter-process communication.

Comment: some examples of how to properly use `popen()` would be nice.

Comment: I've added a link to the Open Group man page for the function, which includes an example. Basically `popen` geves you a file pointer very much like `fopen`. It's just that it lets you write to the standard input or read from the standard output of a program instead of interacting with a disk file. That's unix's *"everything is a file"* philosophy at work. Some implementations extend the standard by allowing bi-directional communication.

Comment: [Thi s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/53372/119527) indicates that `popen` is available on Windows.

Comment: For the solution using the raw file handles (if you need asynch I/O for example), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405985/linux-3-0-executing-child-process-with-piped-stdin-stdout

Answer (score 88):

As others have pointed out, `popen()` is the most standard way.  And since no answer provided an example using this method, here it goes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 128

int parse_output(void) {
    char *cmd = "ls -l";    
    
    char buf[BUFSIZE] = {0};
    FILE *fp;

    if ((fp = popen(cmd, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening pipe!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while (fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, fp) != NULL) {
        // Do whatever you want here...
        printf("OUTPUT: %s", buf);
    }

    if (pclose(fp)) {
        printf("Command not found or exited with error status\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
OUTPUT: total 16
OUTPUT: -rwxr-xr-x 1 14077 14077 8832 Oct 19 04:32 a.out
OUTPUT: -rw-r--r-- 1 14077 14077 1549 Oct 19 04:32 main.c
```

Comment: Shouldn't `if(pclose(fp))` be `if(pclose(fp) == -1)`?

Comment: @CoolGuy: depends on what you want. `pclose()` return `-1` if there was an error obtaining the command's exit status, otherwise it returns the exit status itself. As commands traditionally set exit status `0` to indicate success, by checking `if(pclose(fp))` we're testing for errors in either `pclose()` or the command.

Comment: Thank you so much for this example, it pipes the output of another program to the output of the current program. Thank you!

Comment: Another example: [Is there a way to obtain the output of a linux command (like ifconfig) on a .txt file using a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18297075/4561887)

Comment: Any advantage to using `fgets()` here instead of just `fread()`? It seems like `fread()` could do the same thing without the `while` loop, no? They will both stop if the end of the file is reached.

Comment: @GabrielStaples: `fgets()` is more suitable when reading text output rather than binary, as it automatically fetches one line at a time, splitting on newlines. Both require the `while` loop, as you cannot be sure the whole output will fit in `BUFSIZE`.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX -- it isn't a good idea to make substantive changes to code in the answers of others. In this case your edit introduced illegal C code into the answer. It turns out that [empty braces initializers are not legal in Standard C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295872/iso-c-forbids-empty-initializer-braces-in-c). This is often a source of confusion; they _are_ legal in C++, and it looks like they will finally be legal in C23.

Comment: @adabsurdum: is there a legal way to zero-initialize a buffer pre-C23 in Standard C?

Comment: The traditional way is to use `{0}` in C. IIRC, gcc has supported the C++ style `{}` even in C code for a long time.

Answer (score 11):

popen is supported on Windows, see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx

If you want it to be cross-platform, popen is the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

Well, assuming you're on a command line in a windows environment, you can use pipes or command line redirects.  For instance,

```
commandThatOutputs.exe > someFileToStoreResults.txt
```

or

```
commandThatOutputs.exe | yourProgramToProcessInput.exe
```

Within your program, you could use the C standard input functions to read the other programs output (scanf, etc.):  http://irc.essex.ac.uk/www.iota-six.co.uk/c/c1_standard_input_and_output.asp .  You could also use the file example and use fscanf.  This should also work in Unix/Linux.

This is a very generic question, you may want to include more details, like what type of output it is (just text, or a binary file?) and how you want to process it.

Edit:  Hooray clarification!

Redirecting STDOUT looks to be troublesome,  I've had to do it in .NET, and it gave me all sorts of headaches.  It looks like the proper C way is to spawn a child process, get a file pointer, and all of a sudden my head hurts.

So heres a hack that uses temporary files.  It's simple, but it should work.  This will work well if speed isn't an issue (hitting the disk is slow), or if it's throw-away.  If you're building an enterprise program, looking into the STDOUT redirection is probably best, using what other people recommended.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE * fptr;                    // file holder
    char c;                         // char buffer


    system("dir >> temp.txt");      // call dir and put it's contents in a temp using redirects.
    fptr = fopen("temp.txt", "r");  // open said file for reading.
                                    // oh, and check for fptr being NULL.
    while(1){
        c = fgetc(fptr);
        if(c!= EOF)
            printf("%c", c);        // do what you need to.
        else
            break;                  // exit when you hit the end of the file.
    }
    fclose(fptr);                   // don't call this is fptr is NULL.  
    remove("temp.txt");             // clean up

    getchar();                      // stop so I can see if it worked.
}
```

Make sure to check your file permissions:  right now this will simply throw the file in the same directory as an exe.  You might want to look into using `/tmp` in nix, or `C:\Users\username\Local Settings\Temp` in Vista, or `C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Temp in 2K/XP`.  I think the `/tmp` will work in OSX, but I've never used one.

Comment: `c` should be an `int` because `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux and OS X, `popen()` really is your best bet, as dmckee pointed out, since both OSs support that call. In Windows, this should help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499.aspx

Answer (score 2):

MSDN documentation says
If used in a Windows program, the _popen function returns an invalid file pointer that causes the program to stop responding indefinitely. _popen works properly in a console application. To create a Windows application that redirects input and output, see Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output in the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `system()` as in:

```
system("ls song > song.txt");
```

where `ls` is the command name for listing the contents of the folder song and `song` is a folder in the current directory.  Resulting file `song.txt` will be created in the current directory.

Comment: what if I wanna redirect other programs output into a file ? not an os command

Comment: No, this is a very bad way to do it. Do it properly using pipes, don't be leaving temporary files all over the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer suggested `popen`, it is worth mentioning that `popen` on windows might have unwanted side effects, especially for GUI applications.

> If used in a Windows program, the _popen function returns an invalid
> file pointer that causes the program to stop responding indefinitely.
> _popen works properly in a console application.

I was surprised that there **isn't** a lightweight library that does that **cross-platform**. So I decided to create a library since I need the functionality anyway.

Here's the library
https://github.com/Neko-Box-Coder/System2

It works for **posix** and **windows** systems. (It doesn't use popen for windows so it should also work in GUI applications)

It can send **input** and receive **output** from command.

And have **blocking** and **non-blocking** version.

And it has both **header only** and source version as well

Answer (score -3):

```
//execute external process and read exactly binary or text output
//can read image from Zip file for example
string run(const char* cmd){
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
    char buffer[262144];
    string data;
    string result;
    int dist=0;
    int size;
    //TIME_START
    while(!feof(pipe)) {
        size=(int)fread(buffer,1,262144, pipe); //cout<<buffer<<" size="<<size<<endl;
        data.resize(data.size()+size);
        memcpy(&data[dist],buffer,size);
        dist+=size;
    }
    //TIME_PRINT_
    pclose(pipe);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: What language is it? Surely not C (`string.resize`?)

Comment: looks like c++ :(