# How to redirect output from reading a bash script in c++?

Tags: c++, bash, redirect, stdout

I know that the function:

```
system("myfile.sh")
```

exec a bash script.
Ok but now I want to redirect the output to my program to ensure the reading.
For example the script date.sh give me the date of my system, and i want to see it on my program with std::cout << OUTPUTDATE;
Is it possible?
How?

Comment: Duplicate of: [Best way to capture stdout from a system() command so it can be passed to another function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125828/best-way-to-capture-stdout-from-a-system-command-so-it-can-be-passed-to-another)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `popen` instead of `system`.

The function `popen` will give you a `FILE *` you can read from.

```
FILE *script = popen("myfile.sh", "r");
while (fgets(line, LENGTH, script)) {
    /* ... */
}
pclose(script);
```

Comment: With this method, can I send easly and without error the output to a client on my network?
Thx

Comment: @user840718 With this method you can capture the output of "myfile.sh". I don't know about the clients on your network :-)