# get output of system() into a variable

Tags: c++, c, linux, service, system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to capture stdout from a system() command so it can be passed to another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125828/best-way-to-capture-stdout-from-a-system-command-so-it-can-be-passed-to-anothe)

In linux to get the current status of a service I wrote this code segment::

```
   char cmd[100];
   sprintf(cmd,"service %s status",argv[1]);
   system(cmd);
```

It is running fine and it shows the output on the console like : mysql is running OR mysql is stopped

But I need this console output in a string variable. How can I get 'mysql is running' in a string variable so that I can use this string variable later.
  thankx.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture output then use [popen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) rather than [system()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system).