# Performing system calls from MATLAB Mex files

Tags: matlab, mex

In MATLAB itself, it is very easy to call system commands, such as the following:

```
>> system('ls');
yprime.c    yprime.mexa64
```

(Note: using Ubuntu)

From C(++) programs, I can execute system commands using `std::system`:

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main()
{
    std::system("ls");
}
```

But how can I execute system commands from MATLAB Mex programs?

```
#include <cstdlib>
void mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    std::system("ls");
}
```

^^The above compiles, but doesn't output anything to screen when run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have a look at that thread:

[Capturing stdout from a system() command optimally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125828/best-way-to-capture-stdout-from-a-system-command-so-it-can-be-passed-to-anothe)

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *type);

int pclose(FILE *stream);
```