# Determine if a file contains a certain string

Tags: c, grep

I am looking for a way to determine if a certain file contains a certain string. It can be a system call or a C function, it doesn't matter.

I tried with grep, but it doesnt return anything

```
  //name is the directory entry name
   char grepcmd[150];
      strcpy(grepcmd,"grep -c hello ");
      strcat(grepcmd, name);
      int status = system(grepcmd);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125828/capturing-stdout-from-a-system-command-optimally?lq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-from-c-and-parse-its-output

Comment: Isn't there already a Unix or Linux program / tool / command to print the strings in a file?  If so, you could just look at the source for it.

Comment: ah, i see. it kept returning 0 except for a folder, because apparently all my files contained it. i thought it always returned 0 no matter what. silly me. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing well. `status` should be zero if your given file with name `name` contains `hello` string. Otherwise it should be nonzero value.

Comment: Note the exit code of the command issued via the call to `int status = system("some command")` is retrieved by applying the macro `int exitcode = WEXITSTATUS(status);`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're up for system calls, then just `mmap()` the file and call *something like* `strnstr()`. (You won't be able to call the real `strnstr()` since it will stop at any `\0` in your file, so you'll have to write your own.)

Comment: Will stop on the first `\0` in the file

Comment: @MartinBeckett Not if the OP writes his own. :)