# How to read in result of command processor using C?

Tags: c, shell, terminal, command

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capturing stdout from a system() command optimally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125828/capturing-stdout-from-a-system-command-optimally)

I'm trying to call the function system() and read in what ever output it would produce on the command processor.

```
//system acts as a command processor
char string[250];
system("ls");

//put result into string

return 0;
```

What would be a good way to go about it?

Comment: don't use system.  try popen instead: http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You've asked a perfectly good question; however, it has also been asked before, and the 'possible duplicate' comment tells you of at least one answer to the same question.