# Returning XML from php to c++ app

Tags: php, c++, mysql, xml

I'm trying to use a php script to query a mysql database, make a xml file with the data, then return it to be accessed in the c++ app.  I will then be trying to edit the data returned in c++, like printing or truncating it.  Right now all I have in my main function in c++ is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << system("C:/xampp/php/php E:/phpTest.php");
    return 0;
}
```

my php script includes...

phpTest.pnp:

```
<?php
require_once("mysqli.php");
$connector = new Mysqli_connector();
$xmlTest = $connector->selectTest();
return $xmlTest;
?>
```

and mysqli.php:

```
<?php

class Mysqli_connector {
        var $conn;
        function __construct($db=array()) {
        $default = array(
            'host' => 'hostname',
            'user' => 'username',
            'pass' => 'password',
            'db'   => 'database'
            );

        $db = array_merge($default,$db);
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect($db['host'],$db['user'],$db['pass'],$db['db']) 
            or die("Error connecting to database");
    }

    function __destruct() {
        mysqli_close($this->conn);  
    }

    function selectTest(){
        $res = mysqli_query($this->conn,"select * from loginTest") or die("Error querying");
        $xml_output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
        $xml_output .= "<Data>" . "\n";
        $xml_output .= "field1" ."\t". "field2" ."\t". "field3" ."\t". "field4" ."\t". "field5";
        $xml_output .= "\n";

        for($x = 0; $x < mysqli_num_rows($res); $x++)
        {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
            $xml_output .= $row['field1'] . "\t";
            $xml_output .= $row['field2'] . "\t";
            $xml_output .= $row['field3'] . "\t";
            $xml_output .= $row['field4'] . "\t";
            $xml_output .= $row['field5'] . "\n";
        }
        return $xml_output;
    }
}
?>
```

Using `return` does seem to work when I return from mysqli.php, but then I cannot send it to the c++ app using the same return statement.  Does anyone know the proper way to do that?

Comment: For what it's worth, I know it is creating the XML correctly because if I change the `return` statement to an `echo` it does print what I'd expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as your comment above says, change the `return` to an `echo`. The top-level of any PHP script (e.g. outside of function calls), is **NOT** a function, and has nowhere to return to. In other words, there's nothing "higher" to capture the value you return, so the script simply exits.

Changing to `echo` forces your XML to be actually output, which will be captured by your c++ app.

e.g. If your script was:

```
<?php

echo 'foo';
return 'bar';
```

Your C++ app would see `foo` come back, not `foobar` - the return value is lost because there's no function call to have returned FROM.

Comment: I apologize, I should have been more clear. I need to get the XML as a variable so I can mess with it, not just print it out. So for instance I could then use c++ to get just field1 for each object, rather than print the entire thing.  Is that doable with XML or am I using the wrong format?

Comment: well, I have no idea what your `selectTest()` function is actually doing, but if it's returning xml, then `$xmlTest` will contain that xml.

Comment: Right, but how do I get that into my c++ app to edit the contents of `$xmlTest`?

Comment: Don't use system. it doesn't capture the output, only the exit code of the program you ran. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125828/capturing-stdout-from-a-system-command-optimally