# how to read from stdout in C

Tags: c, pipe, stdout

I need to write a C program (`myprogram`) which checks output of other programs. It should basically work like this:

```bash
./otherprogram | ./myprogram
```

But I could not find how to read line-by-line from `stdout` (or the pipe), and then write all this to `stdout`.

Comment: You're using a `|` pipe, so `stdout` from `otherprogram1` will automatically be `stdin` for `myprogram`. That's all a pipe is - connecting an output to an input.

Comment: Chekout `fgets` from `stdio.h`. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Comment: Are you asking how to do this programmatically in c? What you have there with the | will work.

Comment: Related: 1) [C: Run a System Command and Get Output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/646241/4561887), 2) [How can I run an external program from C and parse its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43116/4561887), 3) [Capturing stdout from a system() command optimally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/125828/4561887) and 4) [the most-thorough C++ answer] [How do I execute a command and get the output of the command within C++ using POSIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/478898/4561887).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an executable using:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char line[BUFSIZ];
   while ( fgets(line, BUFSIZ, stdin) != NULL )
   {
      // Do something with the line of text
   }
}
```

Then you can pipe the output of any program to it, read the contents line by line, do something with each line of text.

Answer (score 7):

One program's `stdout` becomes the next program's `stdin`. Just read from `stdin` and you will be fine.

The shell, when it runs `myprogram`, will connect everything for you.

BTW, here is the bash code responsible:
http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c

Look for `execute_pipeline`. No, the code is not easy to follow, but it fully explains it.