# read stdout of a process in itself using c++

Tags: c++, unix, process, stdout, pid

Consider we have `some_function`  and it prints result to `stdout` instead returning it.Changing it's defination is out of our scope and there's no alternative to it. We're left with option of reading it from `stdout`. So the question.

How to read stdout of C++ program in itself.

It is possible to get `pid` I searched if we can get `fd` of the same programm but I'm not able to find anything.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <iostream>
void some_function(){
    std::cout<<"Hello World";
}

int main(){


    int pid = ::getpid();
    string s = //What to write here.

    cout<<"Printing";

    some_function(); //This function prints "Hello World" to screen

    cout<<s; //"PrintingHello World"
    return  0;
}
```

How to attach pipe to same process i.e instead of creating child process.

Some might think of creating child process and call `some_function` in it, to be able to read its `stdout` in parent process, but No, `some_function` depends on process which calls it and hence we want to call it the very process instead of creating child process.

Comment: I think the simple answer is no. But what is the scenario you are thinking of?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson I have added a code sample above.

Comment: Look up `pipe` and `dup2`

Comment: @EdHeal I have looked for pipe and thought of creating `dup` of `fd` but how to create pipe for same process ?

Comment: I see people voting to close this `:(` , I kindly request consider migrating it to `unix.stackexchange`

Comment: Your question needs some motivation and context. Very likely that you are very confused.

Comment: What exactly is that `some_function`?  What is it doing? What is its signature (exact declaration and name)? On what global state does it depends? Do you have its source code? Who wrote it? Can it be run in a child process?

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is *very* wrong.

Comment: Please provide some [MCVE]. Your code is not one!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No this is a maded up scenario, there's no such function that I have encountered. But it's possibility and has stuck in my mind.

Comment: Then it is very wrong design.

Comment: @EdHeal `pipe()` is dangerous here.  If the called function writes enough to fill up the pipe buffer, it'll block waiting for the pipe to be read from.

Comment: I think there is an important difference if the output is literally to stdout and nothing else (file descriptor 1), and you need to catch it, or if you have some control over which stream the code is writing to. Something in between is if the code uses std::cout and you somehow can redirect it to something other than file descriptor 1.

Comment: Related: [how to read from stdout in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214038/how-to-read-from-stdout-in-c/24214059).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't hard to do, but IMO it's quite a hack, and it won't work with a multithreaded program:

```
// make a temp file to store the function's stdout
int newStdOut = mkstemp( "/tmp/stdout.XXXXXXX" );

// save the original stdout
int tmpStdOut = dup( STDOUT_FILENO );

// clear stdout
fflush( stdout );

// now point the stdout file descriptor to the file
dup2( newStdOut, STDOUT_FILENO );

// call the function we want to collect the stdout from
some_function();

// make sure stdout is empty
fflush( stdout );

// restore original stdout
dup2( tmpStdOut, STDOUT_FILENO );

// the tmp file now contains whatever some_function() wrote to stdout
```

Error checking, proper headers, syncing C `stdout` with C++ `cout`, and reading from and cleaning up the temp file are left as exercises... ;-)

Note that you can't safely use a pipe - the function can write enough to fill up the pipe, and you can't read from the pipe because you've called the function.

Comment: Thank you very much , I'll complete the code and post result here :)

Comment: You could use a pipe if you have an event loop

Answer (score 3):

> How to read stdout of C++ program in itself?

There are very few reasons to do that and that is *usually* (but not always) a design bug.

Be aware of an important thing (at least in a single-threaded program). If your program is both reading from its "stdout" and writing (as usual) in it, it could be stuck in a deadlock: unable to read so not reaching any output routine, (or unable to write because the pipe is full).

So a program which both reads and writes the same thing (actually, the two sides of the same [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)) should use some multiplexing call like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20582916/841108).

Once you understand that, you'll have some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). And before that, you'll make a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) using [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) (and [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html)).

However, pipe to self is a good thing in some [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) handling (see [signal-safety(7))](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). That trick is even recommended in [Qt Unix signal handling](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html).

**Read more about Unix system programming**, e.g. [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) or some newer book. Read also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) & [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

> I have looked for pipe and it requires fd

Wrong. Read much more carefully [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html); on success it *fills* an array of two [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor). Of course it could fail (see [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) & [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) & [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html))

Maybe you just need [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html). Or [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream). Or [open_memstream(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/open_memstream.3.html).

> Consider we have some_function and it prints result to stdout instead returning it. Changing it's definition is out of our scope and there's no alternative to it

If `some_function` is your code, or is some [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), you could and probably should improve it to give a result somewhere....

Comment: Thank you very much, for this, I'll try to come up with something.

Comment: You really should spend several days or weeks in reading more before coding. [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) is a bit old but freely downloadable. And edit your question to motivate it more (very probably you are extremely confused, your question is likely to be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/))