# C code to capture system() data

Tags: c, linux, system

How can I capture the output from `system()` command? For example `system("ls")` should get me all the files in that directory. I am using a linux machine (if that makes any difference). Also I know `popen` can be used to redirect the data as has been answered here

[Capturing stdout from a system() command optimally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125828/capturing-stdout-from-a-system-command-optimally)

but I specifically want to use the `system` command. Is there any way to do it without redirecting the output to a file like `system("ls >> filename")`?

Comment: The answers in that question show how to do it: use `popen()` instead of `system()`. What's the problem?

Comment: As I said I don't wanna use popen I want to use system()

Comment: If you use `system()`, you have to redirect to a file and then read the file.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `popen()` when it's exactly the right function for this?

Comment: The definition of the question which I'm trying to solve specifically says use system()

Comment: Well, `system()` doesn't provide any way to capture the output by itself. That's the whole difference between `system` and `popen`.

Comment: I think that you cant do that thing because system() returns the value of the code execution, and execute a fork to throw the command. if you still want to work with system you'll need to redirect.

Comment: The sequence of calls starts with `pipe` and `fork`, followed by `dup2`, `close`, `close`, `system` in the child, and `close`, `read`, `close` in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a way to do so

```
dup2(out_pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
close(out_pipe[1]);

system(command);
fflush(stdout);

read(out_pipe[0], buffer, MAX_LEN);
```

This can be used to redirect the output from a system command using pipes

Answer (score -2):

you can use popen()
       #include

```
   FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *type);

   int pclose(FILE *stream);

   Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

   popen(), pclose(): _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 2 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _POSIX_SOURCE _BSD_SOURCE || _SVID_SOURCE
```