# How to capture output of execvp

Tags: unix, named-pipes

I'm developing a program which executes a program using execvp. It needs to capture the results of the child process and parse them in the main process. It seems there is a way, using named pipes, and duping. I'm trying to hunt down a good example of this, but so far no luck. If anyone has any pointers, links and/or suggestions about this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Related: [get command output in pipe, C for Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219138/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need named pipes; unnamed pipes work just fine.  Actually, often you can just use `popen` instead of doing the `pipe`/`fork`/`dup`/`exec` yourself.  `popen` works like this (though your `libc`'s implementation likely has more error checking):

```
FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *type) {
    int fds[2];
    const char *argv[4] = {"/bin/sh", "-c", command};
    pipe(fds);
    if (fork() == 0) {
        close(fds[0]);
        dup2(type[0] == 'r' ? 0 : 1, fds[1]);
        close(fds[1]);
        execvp(argv[0], argv);
        exit(-1);
    }
    close(fds[1]);
    return fdopen(fds[0], type);
}
```

This creates an unnamed pipe, and `fork`s.  In the child, it reattaches stdout (or stdin) to one end of the pipe, then `exec`s the child.  The parent can simply read (or write) from the other end of the pipe.

Comment: Great. I've reviewed how pipes work and this ought to do the trick.

Comment: Just for the record if someone stumbles onto this. The conditional based on type[0] is not entirely correct. One needs to close the stdout/stdin before the dup2 for it be possible. Also the pipe is unidirectional and the fds[1] is the write end so it'd need to be  the fds[0] in dup2 for the read case.

Comment: @TommiKyntola from the `dup2` man page: "*makes `newfd` be the copy of `oldfd`, closing `newfd` first if necessary*" so this should work without manually closing stdout/stdin first.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just use popen()?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that demonstrates the use of popen to achieve your goal. Just put something more interesting than "echo" as the command :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char buf[100];
    int i = 0;
    FILE *p = popen("echo \"Test\"","r");
    if (p != NULL )
    {
        while (!feof(p) && (i < 99) )
        {
            fread(&buf[i++],1,1,p);
        }
        buf[i] = 0;
        printf("%s",buf);
        pclose(p);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```