# Streaming execvp output via socket

Tags: c, sockets, exec, pipe, dup

I know this question has been asked a billion times, but all the solutions are not working for me. I need to stream the `stdout` of an `execvp` via a socket to a client. The relevant client  code is this

```
static void execute_cmd(int fd, char *cmd, char **params) {
    pid_t cid;
    size_t i = 0, c = 0;

    cid = fork();

    if(cid == 0) {
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);

        if(execvp(cmd, params) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not execute \"%s\": %d\n", cmd, errno);
            exit(1);
        }
    } else {
        close(fd);
        waitpid(cid, NULL, 0);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

I have tried to copy the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762200/how-to-capture-output-of-execvp). However, I get nothing back when I try this code:

```
int sockfd = serverConnect();
write(sockfd, "echo math", 11);
n = read(sockfd, buffer, 1023);

printf("Got %d bytes\n", n);
printf("%s\n", buffer);

close(sockfd);
```

I triple checked that the connection is established correctly. When I replace `execute_cmd` with a simple `write`, the client correctly prints the answer. But nothing happens when I execute the code above, I get no bytes back. I have removed the `dup2` call and got no output from the `execvp` call either.

Getting quite desperate here, tried `pipe` and whatever I could find. Where did I go wrong? The command itself is ok, too, works on the shell, and the `execvp` call does not throw an error.

Comment: You don't have CLOEXEC set on the fd?

Comment: Note: You're fortunate (actually, *not-so-fortunate*) that `write(sockfd, "echo math", 11);` doesn't crash your process with an access violation. You're reading 11 `char` of data from a memory region only guaranteed to be *10* `char` long (9+1).

Comment: @harmic Uh, not voluntarily. I have no code that would set that, is it set implicitely?

Comment: @WhozCraig I just corrected that before you wrote it, but that has no influence on the problem.

Comment: It is not set implicitly. It would be set using option O_CLOEXEC to open, or SOCK_CLOEXEC to socket or accept, or after opening via fcntl and FD_CLOEXEC.

Comment: @harmic Does that mean I *have* to set it or that it should not be set?

Comment: You should not set it. In any case I was just reading the man page for dup2 and it says 'The two descriptors do not share file descriptor flags (the close-on-exec flag). The close-on-exec flag (FD_CLOEXEC; see fcntl(2)) for the duplicate descriptor is off.' So it should not matter either way.

Comment: When it is set, the corresponding for descriptor would be closed automatically on calling any of the exec functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the code above is correct. The problem was an incorrect use of an earlier `strtok` that resulted in a silent crash of `strdup`. The `fork` above was simply never executed, and all my tests were above the `strtok` line. Only after putting `printf`s into every line of the code I could find the problem.

Frankly, I feel stupid.