# executing a command and getting o/p to a variable

Tags: c, unix, popen

`popen` stores o/p of the specified command into a file. How can I get similar functionality but o/p into a variable (i.e. in a char*) ?

Comment: Have a look a this question (pretty much, duplicate of yours): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219138/get-command-output-in-pipe-c-for-linux

Comment: @Aleks: Sorry, its not what I am asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find anything that returns o/p in a variable. It kind of makes sense as some commands' o/p can be large so to make the behavior consistent, o/p is stored in the file. I actually ended up reading from file returned by `popen`.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

No, `popen()` does not store output into a file. It specifies a *stream*, which *might* represent to a file on disk but which might also be at e.g. a pipe or socket. Streams are more abstract than files.

To have a pipe, you would open the pipe using e.g. `pipe()` and then call `fdopen()` on the proper end of the resulting pipe.

Comment: Thanks unwind. What I want to do is to be able to execute a very simple thing i.e. `wc -l filename` and store the o/p in a variable/buffer. Possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can replace STDOUT and STDERR for the launched command with a stream that you control

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to run a unix command from a C program, and store the output?

If so, then the sequence is to call `FILE* pipe = popen("wc -l filename", "r");` and then read from the FILE* `pipe` just as you would read from a file opened using `fopen`.  That is, you use functions like `fgets` or `fscanf` to read the output, just as you would if the output of the command were in a file.