# Read Value from shell command Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell

Is there a easier way to read the output of a Linux Shell Command 
like

```
ifconfig | grep "inet Adresse" | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F":" '{print $2}'
```

than using `popen()`

```
fp = popen(command, "r");

while(fgets(line, PATH_MAX, fp)!=NULL)
{
      //someoperations
}

pclose(fp);
```

I need to get my info twice before and after some operations.

As my output is just one Line ?

Comment: you can write a small wrapper function..

Comment: `popen` is simple, or Glib's `g_spawn_sync()`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219138/get-command-output-in-pipe-c-for-linux , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-from-c-and-parse-its-output

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Is the question you meant to ask more like _"How can I get the external IP addresses of my computer using C++?"_

Comment: No this command was just a sample command.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll just +1 what pce wrote, then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `popen()` now, was the easiest way Thank you @pce

```
fp = popen(fullCommand, "r");
while(fgets(line, PATH_MAX, fp) != NULL);
pclose(fp);
```

line was type of

```
char line[PATH_MAX];
```

Thank all of you.