# How to save output of a command in char array in c?

Tags: c

I need to make 2 programs communicating with each other using pipes. First program save's it's path in a pipe and sends it to second, which should run `ls` command with that path and send back the output of `ls`. I wanted to send like this `write(fd2, arr2, strlen(arr2)+1);` where `fd2` is is an integer that contains descriptor. I wanted to `execvp("ls ", argv);` and assign it's output to `arr2`, but i don't know how to do this without additions files.

EDIT

Basically the problem is:

How to save the output of `execvp("ls ", argv);` in an array?

Comment: I recommend posting a bigger part of your code than the single calls _you wanted to do_. Better: provide the `main`s of your two application with the pipe creation and the data sending, and explain what goes wrong. It would be easier helping you. ;)

Comment: Perhaps you should use `popen` not `execvp`? See, for example, [Get command output in pipe, C for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219138/get-command-output-in-pipe-c-for-linux).

Comment: If you do not want to execute the two programs in parallel and the size of the first program outputis limited use *popen(cmd1, "r")* for the first program and read and memorize all its output, then use *popen(cmd2, "w")* and write the previously memorized output. Else as you propose use *fork/pipe* and you do not have to save output of the first command in an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execvp` doesn't have an output value (as the fact of returning from an `exec` function is an indication of an error).

If you want to have only the output, use `popen`.

If you want more control (or want to redirect both in and out), read on.

Assuming you want to grab the output of a program you run in `exec`, you need to do the following:

- Make a pipe (use `pipe()`)
- `fork()`
- In one of the processes (usually, child):

  - Set the descriptors so that 1 points to a writing end of a pipe (use `dup2`)
  - Close the reading end of the same pipe and the *other* writing end
  - `exec()`
- In the other process (usually, parent):

  - Close the writing end of the pipe
  - Read from the reading end of the pipe until it's closed from the writing end
  - Wait for the child to exit (note that closed pipe does not equate a terminated process)
  - Use whatever you have read from the pipe.