# How to store the system command output in a variable?

Tags: c++, c, unix, system

I am executing a system() function which returns me a file name. Now I dont want to display the output on the screen(ie the filename) or pipe to a newfile. I just want to store it in a variable. is that possible? if so, how?
thanks

Comment: Which command do you execute in `system()`?

Comment: See this topic : [Run a System Command and Get Output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646241/c-run-a-system-command-and-get-output)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run an external program from C and parse its output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-from-c-and-parse-its-output)

Answer (score 12):

A single filename? Yes. That is certainly possible, but not using `system()`.

Use [`popen()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/popen/). This is available in [c](/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), you've tagged your question with both but are probably going to code in one or the other.

Here's an example in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fpipe;
    char *command = "ls";
    char c = 0;

    if (0 == (fpipe = (FILE*)popen(command, "r")))
    {
        perror("popen() failed.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fread(&c, sizeof c, 1, fpipe))
    {
        printf("%c", c);
    }

    pclose(fpipe);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This will cause undefined behavior at the `printf` call, since `fread()` does not null terminate the string stored in `line`.

Comment: Order of fread parameters are wrong. 2nd and 3rd parameters are swapped. It wont work correctly.

Comment: @vicky: Thanks for highlighting that this wouldn't work with output under 256 chars. Fixed.

Comment: why you return -1 at the end? -1 means it is failed.

Comment: @Amir 9 years after writing this answer I am as puzzled as you are. The main function should return EXIT_SUCCESS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8696712

Answer (score 6):

Well,There is one more easy way by which you can store command output in a file which is called redirection method. I think redirection is quite easy and It will be useful in your case.

**so For Example this is my code in c++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   system("ls -l >> a.text");
  return 0;
}
```

Here redirection sign easily redirect all output of that command into a.text file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[`popen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen)** and read from that file.

```
FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *type);
```

So basically you run your `command` and then read from the `FILE` returned. popen(3) works just like system (invokes the shell) so you should be able to run anything with it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my C++ implementation, which redirects `system()` stdout to a logging system. It uses GNU libc's `getline()`.  It will throw an exception if it can't run the command, but will not throw if the command runs with non-zero status.

```
void infoLogger(const std::string& line); // DIY logger.


int LoggedSystem(const string& prefix, const string& cmd)
{
    infoLogger(cmd);
    FILE* fpipe = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
    if (fpipe == NULL)
        throw std::runtime_error(string("Can't run ") + cmd);
    char* lineptr;
    size_t n;
    ssize_t s;
    do {
        lineptr = NULL;
        s = getline(&lineptr, &n, fpipe);
        if (s > 0 && lineptr != NULL) {
            if (lineptr[s - 1] == '\n')
                lineptr[--s  ] = 0;
            if (lineptr[s - 1] == '\r')
                lineptr[--s  ] = 0;
            infoLogger(prefix + lineptr);
        }
        if (lineptr != NULL)
            free(lineptr);
    } while (s > 0);
    int status = pclose(fpipe);
    infoLogger(String::Format("Status:%d", status));
    return status;
}
```