# How to copy a directory from local machine to remote machine

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp

I am using ssh to connect to a remote machine.

Is there a way i can copy an entire directory from a local machine to the remote machine?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090817/copying-files-using-rsync-from-remote-server-to-local-machine) link to do it the other way round i.e copying from remote machine to local machine.

Comment: It should work ! But unless you give us some error message or missbehaviour instead of saying "doesn't work", we have no way to debug.

Comment: @hivert : You are right, its working. I dunno what i did wrong the first time. I dont remember the error exactly but i am unable to reproduce it. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: The morality is "always copy paste error message when asking on stackoverflow" ;-)

Comment: @hivert: loaded to memory :)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Easiest way is scp

```
scp -r /path/to/local/storage user@remote.host:/path/to/copy
```

rsync is best for when you want to update versions where it has been previously copied.

If that doesn't work, rerun with `-v` and see what the error is.

Comment: What is the lowercase "a" option ?, I can't see any mention in the manual.

Comment: a is normally the archive flag, but I can't find it as a valid option on any of the boxes I have access to now, so it has either been removed, or was never there. Either way, it was safe to omit.

Answer (score 20):

It is very easy with `rsync` as well:

```
rsync /path/to/local/storage user@remote.host:/path/to/copy
```

I recommend the usage of `rsync` over `scp`, because it is highly likely that you will one day need a feature that `rsync` offers and then you benefit from your experience with the tool.

Answer (score 10):

This is worked for me

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh' /path/to/local/dir user@remotehost:/path/to/remote/dir
```

Answer (score 3):

this is if you have to use another ssh port other than 22

```
rsync -avzh -e 'ssh -p sshPortNumber' /my/local/dir/ remoteUser@remoteHostIpAddress:/path/to/remote/dir
```

this works if your remote server uses default 22 port

```
rsync -avzh /my/local/dir/ remoteUser@remoteHostIpAddress:/path/to/remote/dir
```

This worked for me.
Follow [this link](http://lucasb.eyer.be/snips/rsync-skipping-directory.html) for detailed understanding.

Answer (score 0):

we can do this by using scp command for example:

```
 scp -r /path/to/local/machine/directory user@remotehost(server IP Address):/path/to/sever/directory
```

**In case of differnt port**

By default, the SCP protocol operates on port 22 but this can be overridden by supplying the -P flag, followed by the port number for example:

```
scp  -P 8563 -r /path/to/local/machine/directory user@remotehost(server IP Address):/path/to/sever/directory
```

NOTE: we use -r flag to copy directory's files/folders recursively instead of a single file.