# Keep track of filesystem (folders/files) states by saving them

Tags: linux, filesystems, directory

I'm looking for a way to track changes of a folder, with sub-folders and files, from time to time - not in real time.
Basically I want to know which folders/files that was changed (changed or delete) from the last time I looked.

A simple solution would be to make a copy of the entire folders/files and then do some diff when I want to know what have changed. I could touch the files so they wouldn't take up any space and look at the file date to see if it was changed.
...but it doesn't seem like a good option.

This would take place on a Linux system. The file-system I would watch would be mounted (out of my control) but the other file-system would I be in control of, if anyone was thinking about some specific trick for a file-system.

Do anyone got a good solution?

Comment: You can use find command with the -mtime flag. For example, find all files modified in the last 24 hours would be: find /directory/or/mount/point -mtime 1. Finding deleted files is a little more difficult. What's the purpose? Are you trying to backup files?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to backup files. I want to know what was done to the file-system (folders/files) so I might do the same to another copy of the file-system.

Comment: Do you have any control over the filesystem used?  What you're asking for is almost exactly what something like ZFS snapshots can do quite easily.

Comment: I do not think a snapshot would help me since I want to go through a list of what have changed and apply it or not based on some rules.

Answer (score 1):

Git seems like a good solution. You can track changes, go back to different versions of the file, make branches, and get a diff of any commits to what your current state of the file is.

You can do a free class to get started

https://www.codeschool.com/learn/git

You can go into the folder you want to track. Then initialize the folder with

> git init

add all files and folders

> git add .

commit changes

> git commit -m "some message"

after changing files to see changes

> git status

add the new changed files

> git add "the file you changed"

then do a commit

> git commit -m "some message"

Comment: I should have been more clear: The file-system that I will be watching will probably be read-only and even if it would be possible do I not want to add any files to it so using git in that folder will not work.

Comment: @AxAn  Although there might be a better solution you could try rsync to copy all the items to your local system. Then you could run rsync with --itemize-changes to get the difference between the remote and local. Use option -n to not sync. Take a look at 

http://serverfault.com/questions/618735/can-i-use-rsync-to-create-a-list-of-only-changed-files
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090817/copying-files-using-rsync-from-remote-server-to-local-machine