# I am having difficulty importing code from a server?

Tags: python, python-2.7, server, package, requirements

I'm working on a project for a client and his code is running on his server. I've tried to download the code so that I can run a local version on my computer. The project is at least 5 years old and runs on Python 2.7.

The problem is I can't run `python install -r requirements.txt` without running into errors, because some of the files are no longer available. Specifically something called "sorl", "django-page-cms", "mercurial", and a few files the developer hosted on other sites.

If his website is working & the code is functioning on his server, that means there is a working version of these packages stored on the server? How could I find them?

Comment: Can you make available link to the server and/or show the contents of `requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try starting `python` while `ssh`ed into the server and doing an import like:

```py
>>> import sorl
>>> sorl.__file__
'/home/jmunsch/PycharmProjects/projectname/venv_ok/lib/python3.6/sorl/__init__.py'
```

And if the os is the same then `rsync` the files over.

see:
 - [Copying files using rsync from remote server to local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090817/copying-files-using-rsync-from-remote-server-to-local-machine)