# Presentation error in C++

Tags: c++

I am facing an error, that is a presentation error. Being a beginner to c++ , I am stuck on the following question:

> Two cars (X and Y) leave in the same direction. The car X leaves with a constant speed of 60 km/h and the car Y leaves with a constant speed of 90 km / h.
>
> In one hour (60 minutes) the car Y can get a distance of 30 kilometers from the X car, in other words, it can get away one kilometer for each 2 minutes.
>
> Read the distance (in km) and calculate how long it takes (in minutes) for the car Y to take this distance in relation to the other car.

```
Input:
30

Output:
60 minutos (minutes in portuguese)
```

Now, upon submitting the code it says presentation error. Could someone help me find a solution to this error. Thank you in advance.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  int Y;

  cin >> Y;
  cout << 2*Y << " minutos " << endl;

  return 2*Y;
}
```

Comment: This program compiles and runs without any issues. There's nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: Is this a competition problem? "presentation error" means your answer does not match to the expected format.

Comment: and change "minutos" to "minut**e**s"

Comment: It produced a runtime error on ideone: http://ideone.com/LQTzxY.  I believe this is due to the non-zero return (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696698/in-the-main-function-of-a-c-program-what-does-return-0-do-and-mean answer by Brent Worden).  Changing it to return 0; makes it run without any runtime errors.

Comment: @abhishek_naik Really good comment I believe that his presentation error is caused by the fact that he return number different than zero. Simply he should print the output in cout. I hope I understood him well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PE is a common error in OJ of ACM. you can check **space** , **newline** charactor or something you missed.  for example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  int Y;

  cin >> Y;
  cout << 2*Y << " minutos (minutes in portuguese)" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

you can have a try, good luck for you.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem try to return zero as the main function should return it, if your code is clear from errors.

Try to follow that convention to always return 0 in main.

Your code should look like this:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    int Y; 
    cin >> Y; 
    cout << 2*Y << " minutos " << endl;         

    return 0; 
}
```

To conclude simply use *cout* instead of *return*.

Comment: Are you sure this is the 'presentation error' that he is talking about?  He has not mentioned anything about 'runtime error' which is caused by non-zero return (please refer my comment).

Comment: " the higher number it is, the more serious error you have". Is that so? Can you link to a source verifying the same?

Comment: @CinCout Sory you got right I checked one more time and It is my mistake . Thanks for your comment.