# Store system() results in a file

Tags: c++, windows

How to keep writing the results of `system("ping 10.50.132.10 -t");` in a text file using C++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919622/how-to-store-the-system-command-output-in-a-variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A way is to do directly with shell command:

```
system("ping 10.50.132.10 -t >> file.txt");
```

After your operations, you can read from "file.txt"!

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple solutions to this. The first and simplest would be to simple add a redirect in the `system` call:

```
system("ping 10.50.132.10 -t > some_file.txt");
```

Another and more advanced way would be to read the output into your program, and write it out to file yourself. For this look either at [`_popen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).