# Win application calling a DOS command

Tags: c++, c++builder, binutils

How can I call a DOS command and retrieve its output from a windows program that I will program in C/C++?

My prog would be like a "front-end" for the DOS command.

Comment: @Ron there are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898), [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919622) questions for Unix.  Is Windows dramatically more broad?

Comment: @DrewDormann I see. You are probably right. I will retract the close vote. WinAPI really is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way (IMHO) is to spawn the DOS application as a new process and connect your standard output to its standard input and its standard output and standard error to your standard input, using `pipe`s. Then you can communicate with the child process by simply writing to standard out and get output from the child by reading from standard in.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx complete example from microsoft page

Comment: @Alain Paré Rather than posting a "thank you" comment you should accept the answer if it answered your question (of course only if it did indeed solve your problem). Thank you appreciated in any case :)