# return code of system()

Tags: c, unix, system, ps

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int res = system("ps ax -o pid -o command | grep sudoku | grep gnome > /dev/null");

printf("res = %d \n", res);

return 0;
}
```

I want to see if `sudoku` is running or not by just examining the return code of `system()` (or any other call for that matter). I do not want any output to be printed anywhere.

I do not quite understand the return code of `system()` even after looking at the [man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/system.html)

Whether `sudoku` is running or not, I get `res = 0`.

Comment: Did you try to run your code for some other programs, e.g. firefox or vi editor (when they are running)

Comment: Yes, I did try different processes.

Comment: Handy trick: `grep -e "[s]udoku"`

Comment: and why is `grep gnome` in there? That seems to complicate the test uncessarily. To remove all output, you need to add `.. > /dev/null 2>&1`. Good luck.

Comment: If you want to write a shell script, why not just write a shell script? C is a horrible tool for the job.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: Sometimes we need to execute shell commands in a program. See my post for the answer.

Comment: @Aditya of course, but that doesn't seem to be the case here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you are trying to capture the output of `grep` may not work.

Based on the post:
[C: Run a System Command and Get Output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646241/c-run-a-system-command-and-get-output/646254#646254)

You can try the following. This program uses popen()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

    FILE *fp;
    int status;
    char path[1035];

    /* Open the command for reading. */
    fp = popen("/bin/ps -x | /usr/bin/grep gnome-sudoku", "r"); 
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to run command\n" );
        exit;
    }
    /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
    while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {
      printf("%s", path);
    }
    pclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

For reference to popen() see:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen

And if you try to use `grep` then you can probably redirect the output of `grep` and read the file in the following way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    int res = system("ps -x | grep SCREEN > file.txt");
    char path[1024];
    FILE* fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
      printf("Failed to run command\n" );
      exit;
    }
    // Read the output a line at a time - output it.
    while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {
      printf("%s", path);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    //delete the file
    remove ("file.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems that your solution with popen is the one I will have to use.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, you should be using `WEXITSTATUS(res)`. The standard clearly states:

> If command is not a null pointer, system() shall return the
>   termination status of the command language interpreter **in the format
>   specified by waitpid()**.

I suspect the problem is that the command actually succeeds (grep finds itself). Try not to redirect the output for a moment:

```
[cnicutar@fresh ~]$ ./test
  989 sh -c ps ax -o pid -o command | grep sudoku | grep gnome
res = 0
```

So, **since every commands executes successfully**, the return code will be 0 :-). You might have better luck with `pgrep` and the like.

Comment: Thanks cnicutar, but I am not getting you here. `grep` on `ps` is not successful. I also tried not redirecting the o/p, in that case, I can see the command on the STDOUT bur res is still 0.

Comment: @hari You can see it because it actually succeeds (as I explained). Try `pgrep sudoku` instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `pgrep`, use it instead of your shell pipeline.

```
system("pgrep -x gnome-sudoku >/dev/null");
```

---

When you call

```
system("ps ax -o pid -o command | grep sudoku | grep gnome > /dev/null");
```

the system executes

```
sh -c 'ps ax -o pid -o command | grep sudoku | grep gnome > /dev/null'
```

which shows up in `ps` and passes the `grep` filters.

Comment: I am on `ubuntu` and it seems, pgrep is not working:               $ ps ax -o pid -o command | grep gnome-sudoku                    2638 python /usr/games/gnome-sudoku
2657 grep --color=auto gnome-sudoku
$ pgrep -x gnome-sudoku                                            $

Comment: @hari: On Linux, "pgrep" only sees the first 15 characters of the process name (i.e., the "Name" field of /proc/PID/status).  I think you want to add a "grep -v ps" to your pipeline...

Comment: @Nemo: Thanks, are you suggesting to add "grep -v ps" to "pgrep" ??

Comment: @hari: No, I am suggesting ditching `pgrep`, go with your original solution, add add `grep -v ps` (or maybe `grep -v grep`) to the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to redirect the output to a file e.g.:

`> /tmp/isRunningSudoku`

then open the file `/tmp/isRunningSudoku` and store it to your `res` variable

Answer (score 1):

`ps` and `grep` returned succesfully; they `fork`'d, `exec`'d, and they did not return any error status.  That says absolutely ***nothing*** about whether or not `sudoku` is running.

Overall your code is hacky.  However, if you want to continue to hardcode these commands you can use `popen` and observe what the commands actually printed, rather than looking at whether or not `system` succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Try `grep "[s]uduko"`

as full: `ps aux | grep [s]uduko`

This will not show grep itself.

Answer (score 0):

In short, your command will always succeed because it is likely to be reserved in the process space before all the data is interperted.

That means your ps lists itself, and then the greps succeed because

```
grep suduko
```

will match

```
ps | grep suduko
```