# calling commands using 'system()' from inside a program

Tags: c, system-calls

I want to execute some executable files from inside a C program using system(). I want to ensure that the command executed completely; after that, I want to use the output of the previously executed command. For example:

```
{
  ...
  ...
  sprintf(cmd, "./a1.out > temp.txt");
  system(cmd);
  fp = fopen("temp.txt", "r");
  ...
  ...
}
```

In this example, it is not ensured that *cmd* executed completely after that the file is opened for reading. And, I want to ensure that. Any help?

Comment: When `system` have returned, you check what it returned. If it returns `-1` then there was an error. Otherwise the programs main process has run its full course.

Comment: System() returns -1 if excecution fails. Read [docs](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system)

Comment: possible duplicate of [return value of system() in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654089/return-value-of-system-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `popen()` to execute the command and read its output directly.

```
fp = popen("./a1.out", "r");
if (fp) {
    ...
    r = pclose(fp);
    if (r < 0) {
        /*...command exited abnormally */
    }
} else {
    /*...fork or pipe error */
}
```

You can choose to write the data to a file if that is what is required.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the os you are using but under Linux the manual says

> system()  executes  a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c command, and returns after the command has been completed.

Moreover Posix says

> The system() function shall not return until the child process has terminated.

So you are sure that the command is completed.