# How do I make my c++ code know whether a command run from "system(cmd)" failed or not?

Tags: c++, linux, unix

Let's assume I am running a unix command using `system("foocmd param1")` on c++.
If `foocmd` returns "Invalid argument" back to the terminal via stderr, then how do I get my c++ code to know whether `foocmd` failed?

Here is my attempted solution:

My assumption is that I should check whether anything got returned to stderr by calling the command.
To do that, I tried switching over to popen. Currently, this is the way I check. I first output my stderr into a file.

```
sprintf(cmd, "foocmd param1 2>temp.txt");
system(cmd);
```

Then I check if temp.txt is empty or not.

But there has to be a better way. Can anyone lend me a hand?

Comment: `system` returns a status code.

Comment: [Read the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [return value of system() in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654089/return-value-of-system-in-c)

Comment: @GillBates Doesn't it seem like a hassle to figure out what exit code I am looking for? From what I just read, it seems like there is no rule for the exit code, and it depends on how it's coded. That seems to mean that there can be multiple exit codes even though all are errors?

Comment: The documentation for the command you run should document the possible exit codes. If not then you can assume it follows standard conventions, that zero is okay and anything non-zero either means that the `system` function failed or that the command failed (depending on if `system` return a positive or negative value). Basically like if you ran the command from a shell.

Comment: You do it the same as you do in C - the library is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to examine the return value of `system()`:

- If it's zero, the command executed successfully and exited with a status of `0`.
- If it's negative, there was a problem with `system()` itself, and you can't assume anything.
- If it's positive, then you can use `WEXITSTATUS()` and related macros to find out how the process exited.

See the `system(3)` man page for the full details.

---

Most of the time, you are only interested in whether the command says it succeeded:

```
if (!system(cmd)) {
    syslog(LOG_WARNING, "Command \"%s\" failed", cmd);
    /* maybe some more error handling here */
    goto err_return;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it seem like a hassle to figure out what exit code I am looking for? From what I just read, it seems like there is no rule for the exit code, and it depends on how it's coded. That seems to mean that there can be multiple exit codes even though all are errors?

Comment: Most of the time, it's sufficient to simply test against zero: `if (!system(cmd)) { /* error handling */ }` which isn't much hassle at all.  You only pay in complexity when you need it.