# How to read file/folder properties in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

How to retrieve a file/folder's properties in C, particularly in Linux?

I need info about date created, last modified, isDirectory or isFile, permission, ownership and size.

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28system_call%29

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get file information similar to "ls -la" using C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943220/how-to-get-file-information-similar-to-ls-la-using-c)

Comment: good documentation here, I would hate to see this closed as a duplicate..

Comment: @Karoly: What documentation? Everything below is in the man page.

Comment: I prefer to copy-paste code, it saves time...

Comment: Unixes don't save creation time, BTW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely need the [`stat()` function.](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stat)

Example:

```
struct stat attr;
stat("/home/crazyfffan/foo.txt", &attr);

printf("Size: %u\n", (unsigned)attr.st_size);
printf("Permissions: %o\n", (int)attr.st_mode & 07777);
printf("Is directory? %d\n", attr.st_mode & ST_ISDIR);
```

etc.

Comment: The last line does not compile, instead I use:
`printf("Is directory? %d\n", S_ISDIR(attr.st_mode));`

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) system call. `man 2 stat`.

You'll get a structure that includes what you're looking for.

From the man page:

```
struct stat {
           dev_t     st_dev;     /* ID of device containing file */
           ino_t     st_ino;     /* inode number */
           mode_t    st_mode;    /* protection */
           nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
           uid_t     st_uid;     /* user ID of owner */
           gid_t     st_gid;     /* group ID of owner */
           dev_t     st_rdev;    /* device ID (if special file) */
           off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
           blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */
           blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
           time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
           time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
           time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
       };
```

Look over the example in the man page for details about determining file type using the `st_mode` field; here's how to check `isDirectory`/`isFile` using the POSIX macros:

```
isDirectory = S_ISDIR(statBuf.st_mode);
isFile = S_ISREG(statBuf.st_mode);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct stat file_stats;    

fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
if (fd == -1) {
    exit(-1);
}

if (fstat(fd, &file_stats) < 0) {
    exit(-1);
}
if (S_ISDIR(file_stats.st_mode)) {
      printf("It is dir\n");
} else {
    snprintf(msg, PATH_MAX, "%lld, %ld, %o, %d, %d, %d, %lld, %ld, %ld, %ld, %ld, %ld,
    %ld\n",
            file_stats.st_dev,
            file_stats.st_ino,
            file_stats.st_mode,
            file_stats.st_nlink,
            file_stats.st_uid,
            file_stats.st_gid,
            file_stats.st_rdev,
            file_stats.st_size,
            file_stats.st_blksize,
            file_stats.st_blocks,
            file_stats.st_atime,
            file_stats.st_mtime,
            file_stats.st_ctime);
}
```

Comment: without some description of what the fields are for, this is not as helpful as it could be.