# store all processes list into a file with UID

Tags: c

My friend has an below assignment , can anyone can guide how to do this in "C", just guidence is enough.

Write a program to store all processes list into a file and sort all the processes with UID.

For example:

```
./a.out processidlist.txt
```

it has to save the info to  processidlist.txt.

In this processidlist.txt it has to  sort the processes with UID.

he tried the below

```
ps –A –o UID > outputfile
```

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  FILE *fp1, *fp2;
  FILE *fp;
  int status;
  char path[1035];

   fp1 = fopen( argv[1], "w" );
   if ( ! fp1 )
   {
      printf("Error opening file %s\n", argv[1]);
   }

  /* Open the command for reading. */
  fp = popen("ps -Af | sort -k1", "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to run command\n" );
    exit;
  }

  /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
  while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", path);
    fputs( path, fp1 );
  }

  /* close */
  pclose(fp);
  fclose(fp1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [What have _he/she_ tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: he tried with below command , but it didn' twork ps –A –o UID > outputfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something on these lines should work

```
system("ps -Af | sort -k1");

A indicates all processes
f generates full listing
k denotes sort by column
1 denotes first column which is UID of the processes
```

And if you don't want the annoying header

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
```

along with your processes list, then use `sed` to delete first line of `ps` output

```
system("ps -Af | sed "1 d" | sort -k1");
```

Comment: pavan , you mean we can use this lin in c program directly

Comment: If you are running on Linux, then yes! `system` executes a command just as we execute in shell

Comment: you are saying using the line given by you in c program , can you change your code like a c program like the way i asked in the question

Comment: See, as usual,write a regular C program and add the `system` line and then compile/link to get your `a.out`. After that as you've already shown, redirect output to `processidlist.txt`

Comment: pavan , can i do one of the answer mentioned above , it has 24 up points http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646241/c-run-a-system-command-and-get-output

Comment: I did this and its working , but how to redirect the command output to that txt file int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

  FILE *fp;
  int status;
  char path[1035];

  /* Open the command for reading. */
  fp = popen("ps -Af | sort -k1", "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to run command\n" );
    exit;
  }

  /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
  while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", path);
  }

  /* close */
  pclose(fp);

  return 0;
}

Comment: kobe, whats the difference, instead of system, you are using `popen`. And `popen` is to parse output of a command yourself, here `sed` and `sort` have already done that. You just need to do `./a.out >processedlist.txt`

Comment: i think i have to pass file name as command line right , that means i have to handle inside the code? do i need to open connection to file and write ?

Comment: Oh. Ok. Then its easy, just fopen(argv[1],..) and `fwrite`, or `fputs` etc

Comment: thanks pavan , thats , working , can you review my code, i will post the final answer

Comment: hi pavan ,appreciate your time on this question , i posted final one which is working , please review the same

Comment: @kobe seems fine. Why do you need a `printf` there? You want the output into a file right?

Comment: I did both to see the out put , i will remove printf for sure

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the context of the question. i.e. What is the homework assignment trying to teach you?

Is there a specific API you have been learning about to check all the processes? (and so one could sensibly assume you are expected to use it).

If not, something like Pavan's `system()` call might work. (But then why were you asked to write a C program if it's solved by a 1 line shell script?)

Also: the "ps" in the comments on the question - it specifically says write a program, so why did "he" think a ps command line was adequate?

Comment: thanks , then i think we are not supposed to use system command , is there any other simple way of doing that

Comment: Again, what has been suggested by the teacher? /proc on the filesystem directly? libproc?