# Displaying terminal output of shell on client

Tags: c, shell, sockets

I have 2 files Client Side & Server Side

I send a string over the socket from client to server. I have to execute this string as one does in a terminal. The output of the command is to be displayed on the client side.

Server Side Code : this loop runs on each thread created by pthread_create

```
  while((n=recv(sock,client_message,2000,0))>0)
  {

    send(sock,server_out,n,0);
  }
```

I need to run the string i recieve in client_message as a terminal command and fetch the output of the command and send it back via the server_out string buffer.

How do i go about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So - you have two or three different tasks to accomplish.

The first one is to **run the command line** you received on the server. For that, you can start reading the [`system()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) function. It's very straightforward to use.

But then you need to **get it's output**. You can read about this two points in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646241/c-run-a-system-command-and-get-output).

Lastly, **send that data back to the server** - once you have the output stream, it's just `send()`ing that via the socket. You can implement some mini-protocol for telling the other side how many bytes to expect, some error detection/correction if you want, etc.

Once the data arrives the client, then you can do whatever you want with it - print it on the screen, save to a file, you name it.

Read about this things, take your chances, and come back to continue asking if you need it - good luck!