# c programming how to convert system output to char

Tags: c, terminal

I was wondering if anyone can help me:

I need to turn the output of the system command : `whoami` into a variable.

Example:

```
char *a;
a = system("whoami");
printf("username = %s",a);
```

I have tried a few methods such as printing the commands output to a text file like: `whoami >> output.txt` and than making the program read from that file, however i am encountering errors through that method. I also consider that method to be a little messy and unnecessary as im positive that there must be a way within C to let me do this.

This question may be a duplicate so please label as necessary(but also answer if capable)

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If everything you want is read the username you can use getenv http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html

Comment: Thank you @volerag however im not sure that will help unless C and C ++ are more similar than i think they are, thank you anyway though.

Comment: There's mostly C in the accepted answer there, except the `std::string` which you can easily replace with `char *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything you want is to read an environment variable in a POSIX environment, you can simply call getenv:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        char* username = getenv("USER");
        printf("username = %s\n", username);
        return 0;
}
```

If you want something more complex, you can use popen:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html to create a pipe to a process and read from stdout, this answer should help in that case:
[C: Run a System Command and Get Output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646241/c-run-a-system-command-and-get-output)

Comment: haha wow ok, solved all my problems, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646241/c-run-a-system-command-and-get-output) should do the trick. I haven't tested it myself, but I checked and its listed in the Linux man pages so I'm sure its kosher.

Comment: thanks @user1973385, the popen function is a useful lead, thanks