# Retrieving amount of logged on users in c++ in linux

Tags: c++, linux

I have to create a program, that displays result of 'uptime'. how to get amount of logged on users in c++ in linux?

Comment: exactly what does the number of users have to do with `uptime`?

Comment: @MarcB: I imagine he wants to reproduce something like this uptime command: `jake@w700-ubuntu:~$ uptime
 14:29:46 up  5:59,  2 users,  load average: 0.16, 0.16, 0.24`

Comment: @MarcB: From the man page for 'uptime': `uptime gives a one line display of the following information. The current time, how long the system has been running, **how many users are currently logged on**, and the system load averages for the past 1, 5, and 15 minutes.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!
Write in C file system("users | wc -w > text"); and check text.txt file. Next load that information from txt file

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just want to execute commands using C++, you could use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  //execute uptime command
  system("uptime");
  //one way to "count" the currently logged users
  system("users | wc -w");
  //or another way
  system("who | wc -l");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I need to send that information from serverTCP to clientTCP. I want to  put that in string. Maybe there is a way to put system("uptime") result to string?

Comment: yes, check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646241/c-run-a-system-command-and-get-output

Answer (score 0):

That information is stored in `/var/run/utmp`.  This is a binary file; see the `man` page for `utmp(5)` for details.

Comment: As I said, read the `man` page for `utmp`.  It describes how to use that file.

Comment: [Documentation can also be found on the Internet](http://linux.die.net/man/5/utmp).  I've never actually used utmp, so I can't be much more specific.