# How can I get number of Cores in cuda device?

Tags: c, cuda, nvidia

I am looking for a function that count number of core of my cuda device. I know each microprocessor have specific cores, and my cuda device has 2 microprocessors.

I searched a lot to find a property function that count number of cores per microprocessor but I couldn't. I use the code below but I still need number of cores?

- cuda 7.0
- program language C
- visual studio 2013

Code:

```
void printDevProp(cudaDeviceProp devProp)
{   printf("%s\n", devProp.name);
printf("Major revision number:         %d\n", devProp.major);
printf("Minor revision number:         %d\n", devProp.minor);
printf("Total global memory:           %u", devProp.totalGlobalMem);
printf(" bytes\n");
printf("Number of multiprocessors:     %d\n", devProp.multiProcessorCount);
printf("Total amount of shared memory per block: %u\n",devProp.sharedMemPerBlock);
printf("Total registers per block:     %d\n", devProp.regsPerBlock);
printf("Warp size:                     %d\n", devProp.warpSize);
printf("Maximum memory pitch:          %u\n", devProp.memPitch);
printf("Total amount of constant memory:         %u\n",   devProp.totalConstMem);
return;
}
```

Comment: I found a links for cuda 5.0 + visual studio 2012 with sample projects [cuda example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CUDA-50-and-Visual-Studio-20e71aa1), and a link for cuda 7.0 + visual studio [cuda 7.0 getting started](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/#axzz3lScBd2Bm) .

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The cores per multiprocessor is the only "missing" piece of data.  That data is not provided directly in the `cudaDeviceProp` structure, but it can be inferred based on [published data](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities) and [more published data](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/inside-pascal/) from the `devProp.major` and `devProp.minor` entries, which together make up the CUDA *compute capability* of the device.

Something like this should work:

```
#include "cuda_runtime_api.h"
// you must first call the cudaGetDeviceProperties() function, then pass 
// the devProp structure returned to this function:
int getSPcores(cudaDeviceProp devProp)
{  
    int cores = 0;
    int mp = devProp.multiProcessorCount;
    switch (devProp.major){
     case 2: // Fermi
      if (devProp.minor == 1) cores = mp * 48;
      else cores = mp * 32;
      break;
     case 3: // Kepler
      cores = mp * 192;
      break;
     case 5: // Maxwell
      cores = mp * 128;
      break;
     case 6: // Pascal
      if ((devProp.minor == 1) || (devProp.minor == 2)) cores = mp * 128;
      else if (devProp.minor == 0) cores = mp * 64;
      else printf("Unknown device type\n");
      break;
     case 7: // Volta and Turing
      if ((devProp.minor == 0) || (devProp.minor == 5)) cores = mp * 64;
      else printf("Unknown device type\n");
      break;
     case 8: // Ampere
      if (devProp.minor == 0) cores = mp * 64;
      else if (devProp.minor == 6) cores = mp * 128;
      else if (devProp.minor == 9) cores = mp * 128; // ada lovelace
      else printf("Unknown device type\n");
      break;
     case 9: // Hopper
      if (devProp.minor == 0) cores = mp * 128;
      else printf("Unknown device type\n");
      break;
     default:
      printf("Unknown device type\n"); 
      break;
      }
    return cores;
}
```

(coded in browser)

"cores" is a bit of a marketing term.  The most common connotation in my opinion is to equate it with SP units in the SM.  That is the meaning I have demonstrated here. I've also omitted cc 1.x devices from this, as those device types are no longer supported in CUDA 7.0 and CUDA 7.5

A pythonic version is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63823395/how-can-i-get-the-number-of-cuda-cores-in-my-gpu-using-python-and-numba)

Comment: my device is GeForce GT 740M and it has 384 CUDA Cores but what is the right query function to print cuda cores with other properties above?

Comment: There is no CUDA cores property.  You have to use the method I described to compute it.

Comment: why you multiply mp with 192, 32 , 128? what does 192 means

Comment: The documentation I linked by the words "published data" in my answer (click on it!) explains these numbers.  It's not all in a single sentence, so you'll need to read several sections/paragraphs. The 32 and 48 numbers are described [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capability-2-x), the 192 number is indicated [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capability-3-0)  and the 128 number is indicated [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capability-5-x).

Comment: Why is the device prop structure passed by value?

Comment: You could pass it by reference or some other method as well. I don't really understand the question or concern.

Answer (score 21):

In linux you can run the following command to get the number of CUDA cores:

```
nvidia-settings -q CUDACores -t
```

To get the output of this command in C, use the [popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646241/c-run-a-system-command-and-get-output) function.

Answer (score 4):

As Vraj Pandya already said, there is a function (`_ConvertSMVer2Cores`) in the Common/helper_cuda.h file on nvidia's cuda-samples [github repository](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/6be514679b201c8a0f0cda050bc7c01c8cda32ec/Common/helper_cuda.h), which provides this functionality. You just need to multiply its result with the multiprocessor count from the GPU.

Just wanted to provide a current link.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h> // You need to place this file somewhere where it can be
                         // found by the linker. 
                         // The file itself seems to also require the 
                         // `helper_string.h` file (in the same folder as 
                         // `helper_cuda.h`).

int deviceID;
cudaDeviceProp props;

cudaGetDevice(&deviceID);
cudaGetDeviceProperties(&props, deviceID);
    
int CUDACores = _ConvertSMVer2Cores(props.major, props.minor) * props.multiProcessorCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help a bit more.

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/470848/cuda-programming-and-performance/what-39-s-the-proper-way-to-detect-sp-cuda-cores-count-per-sm-/post/4414371/#4414371

"there is a library helper_cuda.h which contains a routine
_ConvertSMVer2Cores(int major, int minor) which takes the compute capability level
of the GPU and returns the number of cores (stream processors) in each SM or SMX" 
-from the post.