# Finding cores from an NVIDIA GPU with python

Tags: python, cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I know I can figure out some basic information about my GPU on an iMac by going under *About this Mac > System Report > Graphics/Displays*. I also know about a similar question being asked [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530604/how-can-i-get-number-of-cores-in-cuda-device) But is there another place under which I could figure out how many cores (I think they would be CUDA cores) there are on my computer? With CPU cores it's easy to figure out, because for Intel, for example, i3 usually has 2, i5 has 4, etc. But how would this work on a GPU from NVIDIA? I have an **NVIDIA GeForce GT 755M**, and I see that VRAM is 1024. Does this help with finding cores? I need this information to hopefully be able to modify the amount of cores used with some python functions, just like one can modify threads per block and such. And for testing purposes...

If there is a way to figure this out with python code (not with C) or under the terminal that would be best. Again, the previous link offers code for C, which doesn't really help me because I don't understand the components of C very much. And checking [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#device-query) doesn't do me any good either because I am not sure how to use that information to invoke responses with python.

Lastly, I'm pretty new to the world of GPGPU, so sorry if this is really basic or I have any misconceptions about the topic.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530604/how-can-i-get-number-of-cores-in-cuda-device) explains how to do it programmatically.  If you read that question and answer carefully, you can figure out how to do it by running the `deviceQuery` [CUDA sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#device-query).  It will be difficult to modify the amount of CUDA cores used by a CUDA code, whether Python or otherwise.  You can't modify it in the same way you modify e.g. threads per block, to use your example.  There are various questions here which discuss this topic.

Comment: Great. I'll give those examples I try. Thank you.

Comment: I'm still having issues. Please let me know if you have any suggestions for finding cores with python code, instead of C. I can't seem to translate the C code properly.