# How do you get CUDA cores count in jcuda?

Tags: java, cuda, jcuda

How do I get the CUDA cores count in [jcuda](http://www.jcuda.org/)?

I've tried this but it doesn't produce the right output:

```
int cudacount = cudaDeviceAttr.cudaDevAttrMultiProcessorCount;
```

It returns 16 but I have 1 Nvidia GPU with 640 cudacores.

The JavaDoc for the above property is [available here](http://www.jcuda.org/jcuda/doc/jcuda/runtime/cudaDeviceAttr.html#cudaDevAttrMultiProcessorCount).
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: it gets 16. but my nvidia gpu have only 1gpu and 640  cudacores (maxwell)

Comment: If you are getting 16 for that call, on a Maxwell GPU with 640 cudacores, then something is broken in that call or in your code or interpretation of it.  You should be getting 5.  I believe the posted answer is correct, but it won't give you the correct answer (640) if this call is actually returning 16.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32531982/1898563) does almost exactly what you want. It's written in C, and the types are slightly different, so here's a Java version (it's hardly any different):

```
int getSPCount()
{  
    final int mp    = cudaDeviceAttr.cudaDevAttrMultiProcessorCount;
    final int major = cudaDeviceAttr.cudaDevAttrComputeCapabilityMajor;
    final int minor = cudaDeviceAttr.cudaDevAttrComputeCapabilityMinor;

    switch (major)
    {
       case 2: // Fermi
           return (minor == 1) ? mp * 48 : mp * 32;
       case 3: // Kepler
           return mp * 192;
       case 5: // Maxwell
           return mp * 128;
       case 6: // Pascal
           if (minor == 1) {
               return mp * 128;
           }
           else if (minor == 0) {
               return mp * 64;
           }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Unknown device type");
}
```

Use this function like so:

```
int cudacount = getSPCount();
```