# Run a system command with system() and send output

Tags: c, linux, popen

So what I am trying to do is to invoke a system command with `system()` function and then whatever its output is I would like to take it and send it over to the client (socket connection).

Client can send various messages. It can be `ls` but it might be even `qwerty`. I would like to take the ouput and place it in the `write()` function as a `const void* buffer` argument. I have seen [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646241/c-run-a-system-command-and-get-output) but I can get it done to work. So far I thought it could go somewhere of these lines but whatever I tried it did not work.

```
/* buffer is message from the client: ls, ls -l, whatever*/
system(buffer)
fp = popen(buffer, "r");
if(fp == NULL)
   printf("Failed ot run command\n");

while(fgets(path, sizeof(path), fp) != NULL) {
  //modify output here?
}
pclose(fp);
write(socket_fd, output, strlen(buffer));
```

Comment: Where do you call `system()`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice right above

Comment: It doesn't seem that a command from the command line will also be a file name.

Comment: You launch the command twice, once in the call to `system` and once in the call to `popen`. Surely that's not what you wanted to do.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice well I could not find any relevant topic to that beside the one I linked

Comment: What part of the question that you linked can you not get working?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I can not send it back to client. I can print it but I do not know how to send it back in `write` function

Comment: I believe the variable `path` contains the output. (This seems like a poor choice of variable names. Rename it to `output` if you wish. Then you can do whatever you want with the data in this buffer, such as send it to `write`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only use `popen()` and not `system()` as it describes in the question you linked.

The `path` variable in the question you linked seems to be misnamed. It contains the output of the system call. You can rename it to output if you wish.

`write()` takes the length of the buffer you are sending it. In this case, that will be the length of `output`, not the length of `buffer`.

Putting this all together gives the following:

```
char output[1035];
fp = popen(buffer, "r");
if(fp == NULL)
   printf("Failed ot run command\n");

while(fgets(output, sizeof(output), fp) != NULL) {
    write(socket_fd, output, strlen(output));
}
pclose(fp);
```