# how to return the return value of a script to a c program using system()

Tags: c, linux

I have a bash script (a very basic one) that is called with `system()` from a c program.

This scirpt calls another script called `./dslite.sh` which flashes firmware to a device.

How could I return the value returned by `./dslite.sh` to the c program?

C program:

```
system("flash_firmware.sh");
```

Script

```
#!/bin/bash

./dslite.sh --mode flash --config=~/configs/device1_config/c1dut2.ccxml ~/images/$1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C: Run a System Command and Get Output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646241/c-run-a-system-command-and-get-output)

Answer (score 1):

From [the Bash manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html), the section about [EXIT STATUS](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#EXIT_STATUS):

> Bash itself returns the exit status of the last command executed, unless a syntax error occurs, in which case it exits with a non-zero value.

That means the exit code of your script will be the exit code of the `./dslite.sh` script.

In other words, you should not have to do anything, the return value of the [`system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) function should be what `./dslite.sh` returned.

---

If on the other hand you mean the *output* that the script *prints* then use [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of `system()` is:

```
int system(const char *command);
```

It does return an `int`.

The following excerpt is from `system()`'s manual page:

> If all system calls succeed, then the return value is the
>             termination status of the child shell used to execute command.
>             (The termination status of a shell is the termination status of
>             the last command it executes.)

So, as long as there is no error at the moment *creating the shell* or the shell's corresponding *child process*, `system()` returns the value of the last command the script executes.