# Store result of shell command in variable in C

Tags: c, linux, shell, cmd

I want to execute the following shell comand inside a C program:

```
find <folder_name> -name "*.bin" | wc -l
```

and store the result in a variable which I have declared inside my program. I don't want the result that indicates if the command executed succesfully, I want the result that tells me how many files ending in .bin exist in my directory. The following code obciously is not working.

```
char command[10];
command = system("find <folder_name> -name \"*.bin\" | wc -l")
```

I need to pass the `<folder_name>` as a command line argument.

How can I accomplish both of these tasks ? I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646241/c-run-a-system-command-and-get-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Retrieving standard output of a subprocess

There's no single function like that in standard C lib. Using `system` you could redirect stdout to a file then read it using `fopen` from `stdio.h`.

To avoid using the filesystem, you could use the POSIX `popen`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *mode);
```

## Passing arguments to a subprocess

If you use `system` you could use standard string manipulation, e.g., `sprintf` to produce the shell command line. This is a little bit brittle if you have special characters in your arguments (whitespace, quotes, etc.)

To pass the arguments directly you could use the POSIX `execl`, also mentioned in the documentation for `popen` above.