# Identification of USB device class

Tags: arduino, usb, midi

how can i know that the connected device is class complaint for MIDI
(Ex; for a yamaha keyboard)
(i'm trying to connect arduino directly to a usb midi keyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in linux you can use `lsusb -v` the device class is in the  `bDeviceClass` field. if it says `0 (Defined at Interface level)` see the `bInterfaceClass` fields. MIDI devices have their own USB class cf. http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/midi10.pdf

on your arduino has to run a kernel module- / driver-like program that enables communication with the USB midi device, because this communication is standardized ( http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml )

on windows you can use tools like `USBView` to get the information about the USB class ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/usbview

Comment: do i have to run lsusb -v in the terminal

Comment: yes in linux. if you want to run this in a C  program see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646241/c-run-a-system-command-and-get-output