# How to handle a c++ file compile inside a C server?

Tags: c

I need to make a server that:
 1) compiles a c++ file and saves the errors in a file if they exist;
 2) if there are no errors i must run the a.out file and extract the output in another file.
 The problem resides in the first one.

In order to compile and extract errors i used more methods:
 1) system("g++ file.cpp &> err.txt") - not working: it prints the errors in the console but the file remains empty
 2) popen - Reference link: [C: Run a System Command and Get Output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646241/c-run-a-system-command-and-get-output) : the only difference is that i opened another file and instead of printing in the console i used fprintf to write in file.
 **I forgot to add that the first method works if written as command in console but inside the server is problematic.**

```
// This code is to show what i have already tried and if you find any
// syntax errors like ; or ' pls ignore them as i couldn't copy the code
// from the docker console. Thank you very much!
//1
system("g++ file.cpp &> err.txt");
if( access( "a.out", F_OK ) != -1 ) {
    system("./a.out > output.txt");

//2
    FILE *f;
char buff[200];

f = popen("g++ file.cpp", "r");
if (f == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to run command\n" );
    exit(1);
}
FILE *o;
o = fopen("err.txt", "w");
while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff)-1, f) != NULL) {
    fprintf(o, "%s", buff);
}
fclose(o);
fclose(f);
```

I expected the errors to be written in the err.txt not to be printed in console and in all the above examples it prints in the console and err.txt remains empty.

Comment: Depending on where the source for the file comes from, you have possibly introduced a really big security hole into your server. Running foreign code without any kind of filtering or containment could let a hacker into your system.

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, the size passed to the [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) function is *including* the terminator. So no need for that `-1`.

Comment: Looks like g++'s output is written to stdout. This is why `popen()` catches it (stdout is the default) whereas you redirect stderr to your textfile when using `system()`

Comment: @flowit i removed the '&' (system("g++ file.cpp > err.txt");) caracter so that i redirect the stdout insead of stderr and still same problem. It still prints in the console instead of redirecting it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for the worries but i've got that covered. :)) The problem is this file compile at the moment -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in the end apparently this one was pretty close: system("g++ file.cpp &> err.txt");
**The solution is: system("g++ file.cpp > err.txt 2>&1");**

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish it the old-school way:

1. `fork()` and in the child:
2. Open a file for storing standard output and another one for errors.
3. Use `dup2(oldfd, newfd)` to duplicate the two files' descriptors to `stdout`, and `stderr` respectively.
4. Invoke `execlp` with gcc and its arguments.
5. In the parent process you can add `waitpid` call to wait for the child to finish.

Comment: Does it work for c++ sources too? I mean the difference is gcc to g++ so it should. Also i am already in a thread with this code.

Comment: @TeodorO. I doesn't matter whether you use c++ or c. These are system calls. Using both threads and processes in the same program is usually a bad idea and difficult to get right, however in this simple scenario where the child pretty much only invokes `dup2` and `execlp` you'll be fine.

Comment: You could also move file opening before the `fork()` call.

Comment: If you're afraid of using both threads and forks in one program, then you can write a simple c program whose only task is to compile the specified file using gcc and store the results in an appriopriate file (by invoking exec, like I've shown in the answer) and then call `system` to invoke that small program from your main multi-threaded one.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try your solution tomorrow and reply with the conclusion.