# C system call fails from second time on

Tags: c, command, system-calls

I am running a program that a given points do a `system` call to zip some files.

The first time it runs properly, but the next time (and also the next ones) it fails with a -1 error code.

```
sprintf(zip, "zip -q -T -m -r %s/datsiter%d.zip %s/*%d.dat", dir, it_number, dir, it_number);
ierr = system(zip); 
printf("Output:%s %d\n ",zip, ierr);
```

The output is:

```
Output:zip -q -T -m -r results/datsiter0.zip results/*0.dat 0
Output:zip -q -T -m -r results/datsiter1.zip results/*1.dat -1
Output:zip -q -T -m -r results/datsiter2.zip results/*2.dat -1
```

If after the run I execute the commands manually, it works as expected.

**EDIT**
Following kaylum suggestion I added `perror("Error: ");` just after `system` call and got the key. A nice `Cannot allocate memory` that I'll have to check carefully since I'm working in a cluster with a queue system.

Comment: Call `perror` to see if there is a more specific error available.

Comment: You might as well try to see what's the stdout output of `zip`, like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646241/c-run-a-system-command-and-get-output

Comment: Nitpick: `system()` is not a system call, though it will call multiple system calls internally, none of which is called "system".

Comment: what system are you running on? windows? linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following kaylum suggestion I added perror("Error: "); just after system call and got the key. A nice Cannot allocate memory that I'll have to check carefully since I'm working in a cluster with a queue system.