# Do other tasks while a system() command is being executed

Tags: c++, linux, system

I have this c++ program that is doing a simple ping on a specified ip address. I am not into networking so i'm just using the system() command in c++ to execute the ping from a shell and store the results in a file, that's easy.

The problem is that i want some dots to be printed on the screen while the system() command is being executed. i tried with:

```
while(system(cmd))
{ 
//execute the task here
}
```

but no success. I think that i should create threads or something.

Can you help me ? What exactly i am supposed to do in order to get this done as i want to ?

Comment: DANGER. Nice syntax but unfortuantely it doesn't work that way.

while() will execute system(cmd) anew *on* *each* *loop*!

Comment: I just realized it..Well that was just my idea after all. I am looking for some way WHILE the system(cmd) is being executed to be able to do other things.

Comment: Can you clarify what OS are you referring to?

Comment: It's Linux, but putting & is not working, maybe because it's specific string being executed. I've heard of threading with linux which will enable one to manipulate with processes like the way i want.

Comment: Reading your application (to ping and print dots), a shell script, perl, or python may be more appropriate.  I believe perl's system() will return a PID.  Also, ping -f prints dots, but that is a flood ping and can create denial-of-service situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a forked process using `fork`, like this, and using `popen` to read the input from the output of the command `ping google.com` and process it accordingly. There is an interesting [guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/singlepage/bgipc.html) by Beej on understanding the IPC mechanisms which is included in the code sample below...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int rv;
    FILE *ping;
    char buf[2000];
    switch(pid = fork()) {
    case -1:
        perror("fork");  /* something went wrong */
        exit(1);         /* parent exits */

    case 0:
        // We're the child
        ping = popen("ping google.com", "r");
        if (ping != NULL){
            fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), ping);
            pclose(ping);
            rv = 0;
        }else{
            perror("popen failed");
            rv = -1;
        }
        exit(rv);
    default:
        // We're the parent...
        wait(&rv);
    }
    // Now process the buffer
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 8):

The problem with `system` is that it suspends execution until completion. On unix systems you will need to use a sequence of fork, execv, dup2 and pipe. This will allow you to do something more useful. See http://docs.linux.cz/programming/c/unix_examples/execill.html for an example.

Comment: Redacted comment: You can save some trouble on the `fork`, `exec`, `pipe` combo by using `popen` if you are satisfied with uni-directional communication.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** On consideration, I believe that popen is the way to go with or without output from `cmd`.

---

**Older**

You are probably looking for something in the `wait (2)` family of commands plus a fork and exec.

From the manual page

> The wait() function suspends execution of its calling process until
>    stat_loc information is available for a terminated child process, or a
>    signal is received.  On return from a successful wait() call, the
>    stat_loc area contains termination information about the process that
>    exited as defined below.

Or if `cmd` returns some progress information you want `popen (3)` which is discussed in a number of existing SO questions; for instance [How can I run an external program from C and parse its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-from-c-and-parse-its-output).

Comment: To him that may mean he actually doesn't want to call wait(), because it will block until the child process finishes, which he wants to avoid. I seem to remember a non-blocking option or parameter, though. Good answer, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a unix system, you can start a command with an & to indicate that it runs in the background like this: myscript &

This will start a new process separate from the current program.  You need to pick up the process number (hopefully from system, my c posix api knowledge is rusty) and then check up on it probably with a call to something like wait or waitpid with non-blocking turned on.

This is complicated for a beginner -- I'll let someone else post details if still interested.