# how to capture result from system() in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I run an external program from C and parse its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-from-c-and-parse-its-output)

Hi,

Could someone please tell us how to capture a result when executing system() function ?

Actually I wrote a c++ program that displays the machine's IP address, called "ipdisp"  and I want when a sever program executes this ipdisp program, the server captes the display IP address. So, is this possible? if yes, how?

thanks for your replies

Comment: Been asked and answered many time. One example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-from-c-and-parse-its-output

Comment: Sorry I didn't know as when I wrote the question, I didn't see related questions . thankS!

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can do this but you can't use `system()`, you'll have to use [`popen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) instead. Something like:

```
FILE *f = popen("ipdisp", "r");
while (!feof(f)) {
    // ... read lines from f using regular stdio functions
}
pclose(f);
```

Comment: thanks a lot! just to clarify please . the variable that display is e.g. (char *xx1;) so how can we get xx1? thanks again!

Comment: Assuming `ipdisp` writes its output to stdout, you'll be able to read its stdout through the file `f` above. Use `fgets` or similar.

Comment: thanks! Actually I have two variables: hostname and ipaddress and I want to capte the ipaddress. is the stdout takes the last displayed one? thanks again

Comment: I wrote a small program as you said, but when I read stdout I get this : Server IP-Address is: 192.168.0.113 and it doesn't display anything. So is it possible to get only this "192.168.0.113". thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Greg is not entirely correct.  You can use system, but it's a really bad idea.  You can use system by writing the output of the command to a temporary file and then reading the file...but popen() is a much better approach.  For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void
die( char *msg ) {
    perror( msg );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

int
main( void )
{
    size_t len;
    FILE *f;
    int c;
    char *buf;
    char *cmd = "echo foo";
    char *path = "/tmp/output"; /* Should really use mkstemp() */

    len = (size_t) snprintf( buf, 0,  "%s > %s", cmd, path ) + 1;
    buf = malloc( len );
    if( buf == NULL ) die( "malloc");
    snprintf( buf, len, "%s > %s", cmd, path );
    if( system( buf )) die( buf );
    f = fopen( path, "r" );
    if( f == NULL ) die( path );
    printf( "output of command: %s\n", buf );
    while(( c = getc( f )) != EOF )
        fputc( c, stdout );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

There are lots of problems with this approach...(portability of the syntax for redirection, leaving the file on the filesystem, security issues with other processes reading the temporary file, etc, etc.)