# Read linux kernel version using C?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am using Ubuntu and I want to read the version of its kernel. I found a file named version in /proc/ that records the version of the current kernel.

If I dont want to read file, is there any other way, like built-in function in C, that I can read the version in C?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to read a file?

Comment: @icktoofay - Because that would be an inefficient way to perform this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the [uname](http://linux.die.net/man/2/uname) function. It gives you a lot of information without the need to parse output of some linux executables.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I need. Thanks all for your support.

Comment: how about actually including the name of that function in your answer, instead of hiding it in the link?

Answer (score 22):

You can use the [uname()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/uname) system call.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to try using the `uname` function.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
system("uname -r");
```

EDIT: type `man uname` in a terminal to get the list of options you can use with `uname`

Comment: This just prints the info on the standard output. To use it in the program, better use the system call.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can read /proc/version, but this is not as good as calling uname(2) directly. uname(2) is more natural to C.

Answer (score -1):

Look at [this](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2007/01/27/how-to-find-your-ubuntu-or-kernel-version/) article for the shell based way of getting kernel information. You can suitably run all of this using the system() call. But I am assuming that wouldn't be enough in your case. You'd need someway to parse the shell output. Hence make use of [popen()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-from-c-and-parse-its-output) call.