# how can I execute c program under another one

Tags: c, c89

How can I execute a c program under another one. Assume you have one c code (program), and you want to call another one. Because you want to send input to it  then score its return data  with comparing another expected return data.

#### try.c

```
int main(void) {
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        /* call another program ( namely, try2.c ) to give it a single input,
        then measure its returning data /*
    }
    return 0;
}
```

try2.c reside in  another FILE.

Compiler is gcc, and under system linux

Comment: What do you mean by "under" ? What is your environment ? Must your code be portable ?

Comment: What on earth happened to the post? I went to go edit it, but it's like half of it is missing!

Comment: I don't want to sound mean, but it's difficult to tell what you want. You should really use decent grammar and spelling, and not abuse StackOverflow's formatting options.

Comment: Stop reverting edits. You're using non-standard formatting for your question, and it is already difficult enough to understand.

Comment: It seems quite rude to close a question after **7 minutes**, that is quite short for the OP to improve it's wording.

Comment: I reedit it, so vote to reopen

Comment: Seems the OP is a C beginner that wants to learn how to create and call a function, but the question was close so fast I haven't had time enough to suggest it could have been what he was looking for instead of running an external program.

Comment: @gcc: I belive the question with the code sample was clearer than the current one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run an external program from C and parse its output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-from-c-and-parse-its-output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`system`, `popen` or platform depended features like `fork` and `exec`