# How do you read the console output from windows commands in C++?

Tags: c++, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I run an external program from C and parse its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-from-c-and-parse-its-output)

If you run a Windows command from inside your program (let's say ipconfig as an example), how do you read the output the system gives you back into your program for processing?

Answer (score 3):

See [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN

Alternatively, you can use [_popen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for simple capture of output.