# Disabling STM32 HAL IWDG or WWDG (watchdog) before STOP mode

Tags: stm32, watchdog, hal

I using an STM32 (L0 5) HAL I need to disable IWDG or WWDG before entering in STOP mode. The below code is working fine until IWDG is resetting the MCU from STOP mode. For WWDG  usage this is much faster and reset before HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode is called, despite HAL_WWDG_Refresh is called after each line.  I tested also those scenarios also on Nucleo L05.

```
iwdgHandle.Instance = IWDG;
iwdgHandle.Init.Prescaler = IWDG_PRESCALER_64;
iwdgHandle.Init.Window = 4095;
iwdgHandle.Init.Reload = 4095;
if (HAL_IWDG_Init(&iwdgHandle) != HAL_OK) // almost 7secs until refresh has to be called
{
 _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
}

HAL_PWR_EnableWakeUpPin(WakeSpi_Pin);
HAL_PWREx_EnableUltraLowPower(); // Enable Ultra low power mode
HAL_PWREx_EnableFastWakeUp(); // Enable the fast wake up from Ultra low power mode

HAL_SuspendTick();
HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON, PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI);
```

Comment: In the meanwhile I found the following: : ''the IWDG is started by writing to its Key register or by hardware option. Once started it cannot be stopped except by a Reset.''

Comment: also from ST:  One of the differences between WWDG and IWDG is that IWDG has independent clock. The WWDG is clocked from APB bus whose frequency is derived from the core clock (SYSCLK). Due to the fact that the core clock is stopped in STOP mode the WWDG clock is stopped as well. This means it is automatically stopped in STOP low-power mode and you don't have to refresh it. With IWDG you would have to wake-up regularly and refresh it. Microcontrollers from 

STM32L4 family allow to stop also IWDG in STOP mode (by setting corresponding option byte).

Answer (score 6):

The Independent watchdog can not be stopped in any processor mode. You have to wake up regularly to reload the watchdog. What you can do is change the prescaler to maximum so the watchdog is counting slowly.

IWDG will only be stopped if you disconnect the controller from the power supply.

Comment: Same behaviour seems to be also with WWDG. Does this can be disabled before going to STOP?

Comment: @Colateral No, with watchdogs generally once you set them going that's it. It's to prevent code from accidentally turning it off again in a fault state.

Comment: I have to correct myself! In shutdown mode, all clocks except LSE are off. So, if your WDG is running for example on LSI, reloading is not necessary. See chapter Power control for an overview of sleep modes and clock behavior.

Comment: Note: For debugging purposes, the Independent Watchdog (IWDG) can be stopped when the core is halted (see DBG_IWDG_STOP (in the Debug MCU freeze register) in the reference manual).

Comment: For WWDG, you can disable using  __HAL_RCC_WWDG_CLK_DISABLE();

Comment: Note that disabling it using __HAL_RCC_WWDG_CLK_DISABLE should be considered a brittle workaround and is not portable : I have used that approach on an stm32F4 but on a stm32G4 the same trick is not preventing a wwdg induced reset.

Answer (score 1):

I have the (somehow) same problem, so it's what I have done:

I use HAL library, and it firstly initializes `HAL_Init();`, then calls `SystemClock_Config();`, and after that it starts initializing peripherals, including `iwdg`. (**You can also do it without HAL**).

So, when I want to go to stop mode, I restart the system using `HAL_NVIC_SystemReset();`, and when micro restarts, just after `SystemClock_Config();` I check for previous system restart reason ([check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34196663/stm32-how-to-get-last-reset-status)). If it's software reset, I go to stop mode and don't let IWDG to be initialized.

Simple, easy.

psudo code:

```
1. instead of directly going to STOP mode -> make a software restart using HAL_NVIC_SystemReset();

//After restart and configuring system clocks (before initializing other peripherals)
2. if(previous restart reason == software restart) { 
        goto stop mode /* we don't init iwdg */
    } else {
        continue initializing peripherals.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a flash option byte that you can clear that will prevent the IWDG or the WWDG timers from counting while in stop mode.

Comment: Where is it bruv?

Comment: @MohammadKholghi The USER option bytes contain the bits for controlling if the IWDT is frozen or running in stop or standby mode.  Clear bit 17 to freeze the IWDT in stop mode.  Clear bit 18 to freeze the IWDT in standby mode.  You can use `HAL_FLASHEx_OBProgram` in stm32l4xx_hal_flash_ex.c to configure the option bytes.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, there is a solution involving option bytes. I utilized the STM32Cube Programmer application and disabled the IWDG_STOP option within the user options. This action freezes the watchdog timer when entering the stop mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have selected the suspend watchdog counters when
halted in the debug options.

[image]

This code is in the first user section after init in main().
In the .ioc file I have set the
pre scaler to 128 (at 168MHz gives about 3.12 mS per WD count)
the window value at 120, and the free runner counter reset to 127

That means between 127 and 120 trying to refresh will cause
a restart. Between 119 and 64 you can refresh the WWDG (this
is a very wide window also the code I have is cheating in that its looking at the internal registers, i.e. its for debugging the thing; IRL you should use it to validate timing of task loops etc)

```
  // code to put in main() user init
  //
  int i,old_i=0,cnt=0;
  do {
      //HAL_WWDG_MspInit(&hwwdg);
      int i = hwwdg.Instance->CR;
      if ( (i-128) < 120 ) HAL_WWDG_Refresh(&hwwdg);
      asm("nop");
      HAL_Delay(1);
      cnt++;
  }
  while ( i == old_i && cnt );
```

This is the watchdog as I have it set for DEBUG (with a wide refresh window).

The hwwdg.Instance->CR register seems to hold the count+128.
But using this code with 1mS delays etc I can refresh the WWDG .
The cnt variable gives an indication of how many milli-seconds have passed before the watchdog has counted down sufficiently to
allow a valid refresh.

For the last few hours I was simply getting mystery resets!

[image]

Solved for me!
I;ll tighten the window and configure it for my tasking model.