# How do I read in the Enter key as an input in C?

Tags: c, input, stdin

How do I read in the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key as an input in C? I'd like some program like this:

```
"Please enter a key to go to next line"
```

How do I add this type of option in C?

I am new to programming.

Comment: Can you please write the code please

Comment: Since keyboard input is usually line-buffered in C, you can just write `getchar()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getc` function in `stdio.h` to wait until a key is pressed. This C code will wait for the enter key to be pressed then output "Continued!":

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Press any key to continue");
    getc(stdin);
    printf("Continued!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But I can't find the "any" key! Seriously, though, have you tried this? It doesn't work with any key, just the Enter key.

Comment: This code take only enter key as an input

Comment: @TapabrataGoswami I made a mistake, this code only works with the enter key like you need

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can write:

```
printf("Press ENTER key to Continue\n");  
getchar();
```

Or

```
printf("Press Any Key to Continue\n");
getch();
```

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of `getc()` demos in C:

### 1. To also print out what key was entered, do this:

**read_in_any_key.c:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Press any key followed by Enter, or just Enter alone, to continue: ");
    int c = getc(stdin);
    printf("The first character you entered is decimal %i (\"%c\").\n", c, c);

    return 0;
}
```

Example runs and output. Notice in the last example I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone, so it printed it as a newline. The decimal numbers for each key can be found in an ASCII table, like this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_code_chart.

> ```
> eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c17 read_in_enter_key.c -o bin/a && bin/a
> Press any key followed by Enter, or just Enter alone, to continue: abc
> The first character you entered is decimal 97 ("a").
> ```

> ```
> eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c17 read_in_enter_key.c -o bin/a && bin/a
> Press any key followed by Enter, or just Enter alone, to continue: def
> The first character you entered is decimal 100 ("d").
> ```

> ```
> eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c17 read_in_enter_key.c -o bin/a && bin/a
> Press any key followed by Enter, or just Enter alone, to continue: FTL
> The first character you entered is decimal 70 ("F").
> ```

> ```
> eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c17 read_in_enter_key.c -o bin/a && bin/a
> Press any key followed by Enter, or just Enter alone, to continue: 
> The first character you entered is decimal 10 ("
> ").
> ```

### 2. To print out all of the keys typed, in case multiple keys were pressed before pressing Enter, do this:

**read_in_any_key.c:**

```c
#include <stdint.h>  // For `uint8_t`, `int8_t`, etc.
#include <stdio.h>   // For `printf()`

// int main(int argc, char *argv[])  // alternative prototype
int main()
{
    printf("Press any key followed by Enter, or just Enter alone, to continue: ");
    int c = getc(stdin);
    printf("The first character you entered is decimal %i (\"%c\").\n", c, c);

    // If you entered one or more characters above before pressing Enter, they
    // are still in the stdin input stream's buffer, so let's read those out
    // too, up to the newline char (`'\n'`) created by pressing Enter.
    uint32_t charNum = 2;
    while (c != '\n')
    {
        c = getc(stdin);
        if (c == EOF)
        {
            printf("Failed to get char!\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("char %-2u = decimal %i (\"%c\").\n", charNum, c, c);
        charNum++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example run and output. I typed `abcdefghijklmnop` and then pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c17 read_in_any_key.c -o bin/a && bin/a
Press any key followed by Enter, or just Enter alone, to continue: abcdefghijklmnop
The first character you entered is decimal 97 ("a").
char 2  = decimal 98 ("b").
char 3  = decimal 99 ("c").
char 4  = decimal 100 ("d").
char 5  = decimal 101 ("e").
char 6  = decimal 102 ("f").
char 7  = decimal 103 ("g").
char 8  = decimal 104 ("h").
char 9  = decimal 105 ("i").
char 10 = decimal 106 ("j").
char 11 = decimal 107 ("k").
char 12 = decimal 108 ("l").
char 13 = decimal 109 ("m").
char 14 = decimal 110 ("n").
char 15 = decimal 111 ("o").
char 16 = decimal 112 ("p").
char 17 = decimal 10 ("
").
```

### 3. To only continue if <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed alone, with nothing else before it, do this:

**read_until_only_enter_key.c:**

```c
#include <stdbool.h> // For `true` (`1`) and `false` (`0`) macros in C
#include <stdio.h>   // For `printf()`

// Clear the stdin input stream by reading and discarding all incoming chars up to and including
// the Enter key's newline ('\n') char. Once we hit the newline char, stop calling `getc()`, as
// calls to `getc()` beyond that will block again, waiting for more user input.
void clearStdin()
{
    // keep reading 1 more char as long as the end of the stream, indicated by the newline char,
    // has NOT been reached
    while (true)
    {
        int c = getc(stdin);
        if (c == EOF || c == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Returns true if only Enter was pressed, and false otherwise
bool getOnlyEnterKeypress()
{
    bool onlyEnterPressed = false;
    printf("Press ONLY the Enter key to continue: ");
    int firstChar = getc(stdin);
    if (firstChar == '\n')
    {
        printf("Good! You pressed ONLY the Enter key!\n");
        onlyEnterPressed = true;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You failed. You pressed another key first.\n");
        clearStdin();
    }
    return onlyEnterPressed;
}

// int main(int argc, char *argv[])  // alternative prototype
int main()
{
    while (!getOnlyEnterKeypress()) {};

    return 0;
}
```

Example run and output. Notice that the program didn't exit until the very end when I presed only <kbd>Enter</kbd>, withOUT more keys before it first.

```
eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c17 read_until_only_enter_key.c -o bin/a && bin/a
Press ONLY the Enter key to continue: a
You failed. You pressed another key first.
Press ONLY the Enter key to continue: abc
You failed. You pressed another key first.
Press ONLY the Enter key to continue: w
You failed. You pressed another key first.
Press ONLY the Enter key to continue:
Good! You pressed ONLY the Enter key!
```

If you'd like to read keypresses *instantly*, rather than waiting for the Enter key to be pressed, see the link at the top of the "Going Further" section just below.

### References:

1. [Answer by @Justiniscoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70976036/4561887)
2. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc
3. https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getc/

### Related/Going Further:

1. [my answer] How to read keypresses *instantly* rather than waiting for Enter: [Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70979820/4561887)
2. [What is the equivalent to getch() & getche() in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7469139/4561887)
3. [How to avoid pressing Enter with getchar() for reading a single character only?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1798511/4561887)
4. [Read Key pressings in C ex. Enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12709256/4561887)

Answer (score 0):

Only one other answer properly touches on this. Do not assume your user will obey you, even if he or she intended to.

```
// Ask user to do something
printf( "Press Enter to continue: " );
fflush( stdout );

// Wait for user to do it
int c;
do c = getchar();
while ((c != EOF) and (c != '\n'));
```

This discards other input until the Enter key is pressed or EOF is reached, leaving your input stream in a known state.

If you wish to have unbuffered input, that is a whole different can of worms.