# How to check if input is empty?

Tags: c, scanf, stdin

How to check if user inputs nothing and presses enter only? If that happens then error message and code stops. In C language.

I tried `== '\n'` and `" "` but nothing works :(

```
int main() {
    int number;
    printf("Number 1-8: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &number) != 1 || number < 1 || number > 8 || number == '\n') {
        printf("error");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't do it with `scanf()`, it will keep waiting for the user to enter a number. Use `fgets()` to read a whole line, then check if the line is empty (don't forget that `fgets()` returns the newline, you have to ignore that).

Comment: Note that `number == '\n'` is never true here for `%d`. You're mistaken somewhere, or you didn't enter what you said: `scanf` won't return until you enter something for `%d`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read in the Enter key as an input in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70975906/how-do-i-read-in-the-enter-key-as-an-input-in-c)

Comment: @WeatherVane `number == '\n'` is true for number 10.

Answer (score 5):

The `scanf` specifier `%d` will consume any and all<sup>1</sup> leading whitespace, which includes line feeds (the newline character).

Instead of using `scanf`, read an entire line into an array with `fgets`. Then do whatever it is you need to do with that data.

An empty string is a string that begins with the null-terminating byte. `sscanf` can be used to parse a string similar to how `scanf` parses standard input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char line[512];

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter a value between 1 - 8: ");

        if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
            if (ferror(stdin))
                perror("stdin");
            break;
        }

        /* remove trailing new line character */
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';

        /* an empty line - first character is the null-terminating byte */
        if (!line[0]) {
            fputs("You entered nothing! Try again.\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }

        /* allow the user to exit the prompt */
        if (0 == strcmp(line, ".exit"))
            break;

        int value;

        if (1 == sscanf(line, "%d", &value)) {
            if (1 <= value && value <= 8) {
                printf("Got valid value: <%d>\n", value);
            } else {
                printf("Value <%d> out of range.\n", value);
            }
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not parse number from <%s>\n", line);
        }
    }
}
```

```
Enter a value between 1 - 8: 
You entered nothing! Try again.
Enter a value between 1 - 8: 7
Got valid value: <7>
Enter a value between 1 - 8: 123
Value <123> out of range.
Enter a value between 1 - 8: foobar
Could not parse number from <foobar>
Enter a value between 1 - 8: .exit
```

---

See also: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2505965)

<sup>*1. Assuming no errors occur.*</sup>

Comment: Nice!  Should you care for a pedantic point about `if (ferror(stdin))` vs. [`if (!feof(stdin))`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53274876/2410359).