# ISO C forbids empty initializer braces in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization

I have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct
{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
   int d;
} Hello;
```

then I declare it in this way:

```
Hello hello[6] = {};
```

Then I got this warning: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces, anyhow I think I need to initialize it, how to do it in the right way?

Comment: You can initialize each array element and each element's members as `Hello hello[6] = {{1,2,3,4}, <repeat 5 times>};`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Hello hello[6] = {{0}};
```

Will initialize all members of each struct to 0.

Answer (score 14):

That's not valid C. The universal zero initializer in C is `{0}`, not `{}`.

Comment: Agree with this, but this solution is also confusing because it means `One initializes the first element to zero, the remaining elements will be initialized to zero by default`. Some people think `{1}` would initialize the struct/array to `1`.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:-

```
  Hello hello[6] = {{0}};
```

This will initialize all the members of struct to 0.