# how to remove program from startup list using c++

Tags: c, windows

Am trying to Remove application from startup list but no success , error code is zero , so need help my function code is

```
string appName="someapp";
REGSAM flag = KEY_WOW64_64KEY; 
HKEY hkey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"),NULL, KEY_READ | KEY_WRITE | flag,&hkey);
RegDeleteValue(hkey,appName.c_str());
cout<<"\n error code is "<<GetLastError();
RegCloseKey(hkey);
```

Comment: Similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-from-c-and-parse-its-output

Comment: @Makis What??? Surely you posted the wrong link.

Comment: I thought he wants the output from another application ("how we are going to get back result from system command").

Comment: @Makis ya thats problem .... well anyother idea how to remove application from startup list using c++

Comment: Alright, I yield, the English in this question is too strange for me to comprehend...

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the register key with a Windows API function, see [register function reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), particularly [RegDeleteKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The key in this case should be below HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, then SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run. To check if they key exists, use RegOpenKeyEx.