# VS c++ Deleting subkey doesn't work! Error code 0

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, key, registry

I am currently trying to delete a subkey from "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run". The problem is dispite having tried every possible solution out there my error code is unique and the only question about it hasn't been answered: [how to remove program from startup list using c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730389/how-to-remove-program-from-startup-list-using-c) . I am using Visual Studio on Windows x64 10 the programm is a Win32 application.

Created key with:

```
   BOOL registerForLocalStartup(PCWSTR regName, PCWSTR pathToExe, PCWSTR args)
{
    HKEY hKey = NULL;
    LONG lResult = 0;
    BOOL fSuccess = TRUE;
    DWORD dwSize;

    const size_t count = MAX_PATH * 2;
    wchar_t szValue[count] = {};


    wcscpy_s(szValue, count, L"\"");
    wcscat_s(szValue, count, pathToExe);
    wcscat_s(szValue, count, L"\" ");

    if (args != NULL)
    {
        // caller should make sure "args" is quoted if any single argument has a space
        // e.g. (L"-name \"Mark Voidale\"");
        wcscat_s(szValue, count, args);
    }

    // For admin HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
    lResult = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, NULL, 0, (KEY_WRITE | KEY_READ), NULL, &hKey, NULL);

    fSuccess = (lResult == 0);

    if (fSuccess)
    {
        dwSize = (wcslen(szValue) + 1) * 2;
        lResult = RegSetValueExW(hKey, regName, 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)szValue, dwSize);
        fSuccess = (lResult == 0);
    }

    if (hKey != NULL)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        hKey = NULL;
    }

    return fSuccess;
}
```

Here my code:

```
bool DeleteValueKey(HKEY hKeyRoot, std::wstring Subkey, std::wstring ValueKey)
{
    HKEY    hKey = NULL;
    bool    bReturn = false;

    long result = RegOpenKeyEx(hKeyRoot, Subkey.c_str(), 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WRITE | KEY_WOW64_32KEY, &hKey);

    wcout << "Result of RegOpenKeyEx: " << result << endl;

    if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        long result2 = RegDeleteKeyEx(hKey, ValueKey.c_str(), KEY_WOW64_32KEY, 0);
        wcout << "Result of RegDeleteKeyEx: " << result2 << endl;
        if (result2 == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            bReturn = true;
        }
    }

    if (hKey != NULL) { RegCloseKey(hKey); }

    return bReturn;
}
```

And this is what I tried to call:

```
bool result = DeleteValueKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", L"test1");

            if (result)
            {
                wcout << "SUCCESS" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                wcout << "FAILURE: "<< GetLastError() << endl;
            }*/
```

OUTPUT:

```
Result of RegOpenKeyEx: 0 
Result of RegDeleteKeyEx: 2 
FAILURE: 0
```

Has someone an idea ? I am going crazy not beeing able to fix such a blatant issue...

Comment: Why do you not examine the return value of the registry functions to see what the actual error is - your code discards this important information.

Comment: Is your program 32 bit or 64 bit?  Is your Windows 32 bit or 64 bit?  What error code are you getting?  What does `::GetLastError()` return?

Comment: I use Windows x64 and my application is x32. The error code I am getting is 0.

Comment: _"Result of RegDeleteKeyEx: 2"_ 2 is Not Found  Also you only pass KEY_WOW64_32KEY into delete.  Therefore Open and Delete are seeing different views of the registry

Comment: I am checking with autoruns the key is there!

Comment: I already tried adding  | KEY_WOW64_32KEY to Open but it didn't help the error messages are the same.

Answer (score 1):

To delete your **value** in the Run **key** you should use [`RegDeleteKeyValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724848(v=vs.85).aspx) (or `RegDeleteValue` if you support WinXP and older).

`RegDeleteKeyEx` is used to delete the whole key (and all its values) and you don't want to do that here because you don't own the Run key.

See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090204-00/?p=19263) for the terminology used to describe the various parts of the registry.